# how to bind enum values to strings

Tags: c#

In my project there is an UI which contains a combobox and the combobox will list some communication protocol, such as TCP/IP, FTP and so on

I want to use an enum to present the communication protocols, maybe like this:

```
public enum CommuProtocol 
{
   TCPIP = 0,
   FTP,
   MPI,
   Other
}
```

so, how to bind the enum value to the text in combobox. For example, from the text selected in combobox I can easily know the corresponding enum value and vice versa. And I hope that will be easy to be extended in the future.

**The text maybe not the same with the enum value, etc, TCP/IP vs TCPIP...**

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, either you make a function which translates the values into strings or you [ToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16c1xs4z.aspx) the value:

```
CommuProtocol prot = CommuProtocol.FTP;
string name = prot.ToString();
```

You can use the name of the enum member to get a proper value with the [parse member of Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx):

```
CommuProtocol prot = System.Enum.Parse(CommuProtocol, "FTP");
```

However, since the names of the members might not be suitable for display it's possible that you'll end up making a method that translates the names anyway.

Comment: the prolbem is: the enum value is not the same with text, such as TCP/IP and TCPIP

Comment: Nice solution to use the ToString(), I was going to suggest the old C/C++ way of delaring an array of strings and using the enum as the index. I'm glad you replied before I did!

Comment: Hehe thanks. I've had to do this quite a lot of times myself.

Carlos: if you can't use the names, you'll have to devise a way to translate "TCP/IP" into "TCP" or the reverse. It could be as simple as a method with a big switch-statement in it. You are not using WPF are you? There is a more elegant way if so.

Comment: You are not using WPF are you?
------------------
No :-(

Comment: Nothing wrong with a switch to output the correct name.  It is there for a reason!

Comment: Indeed... that or store it in a small table which maps them. Net result is the same.

Answer (score 2):

You should go with [`Enum.GetValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues.aspx) method. Here is an example: [How do you bind an Enum to a DropDownList control in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953/how-do-you-bind-an-enum-to-a-dropdownlist-control-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 2):

This gets asked a lot. See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953/how-do-you-bind-an-enum-to-a-dropdownlist-control-in-asp-net).