# string.join not working Enum.GetValues c#

Tags: c#, string, enums

I have an Enum abc(N=0,Y=1,M=2), i want to convert it to CSV so I used string.Join as below

```
var abc_arr = Enum.GetValues(typeof(abc));
var abc_csv = string.Join("','", abc_arr );
```

But it does not return **N,Y,M** but instead returns "System.abc[]"
Why?

**Well the problem is Enum.GetValues is strongly typed so you have to explicitly set the resulting type**

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213432/why-does-enum-getvalues-return-names-when-using-var and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398664/enum-getvalues-return-type

Answer (score 3):

If you want the names, you should use: `Enum.GetNames(typeof(abc))`. `GetValues` returns the values of the enum. If you want that, you can do it via a cast: `(int[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(abc))`

Answer (score 1):

You should cast first the result of `GetValues`:

```
var abc_arr = (abc[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(abc));
var abc_csv = string.Join(",", abc_arr );
```

Furthermore, I changed a bit your separator.

You could take a look [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hzquSv) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

```
var abc_arr = Enum.GetNames(typeof(abc));
var csv = string.Join(",", abc_arr);
```

You should call GetNames to return string[] of the names, also your separator should not have `','`. It should be only `,`

Comment: I have to use it in an sql query so I used ',' not ,

Comment: @irfandar okay add it if you need it.