# How to add drop down list values by enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I want to add the below values from Enum to drop down list

```
<option value="0">-- Select --</option>
<option value="AC">Active</option>
<option value="IN">InActive</option>
<option value="PC">Pending Closure</option>
```

thanks,
Vara Prasad.M

Comment: That's interesting.  Are you having problems with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible. Check the Question: [How do you bind an Enum to a DropDownList control in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953/how-do-you-bind-an-enum-to-a-dropdownlist-control-in-asp-net)

Comment: It only works if the names are simple strings with no spaces and if the values are integers. His example breaks both.

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't because [you can't](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). An enum must be of an [integral type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and a name of a keyword can't be `0` or have a space in it's name so it's impossible to convert them to a string to reach your goal. Converting the keyword to a string is also not something I recommend.