# Populating dropdown list with enum using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, reflection, enums, drop-down-menu

I am populating a page with controls reading properties of a class using reflection. If the property type is `'String'` I will add a text-box. If the property type is enum I am adding a dropdownlist. Now I have to populate the dropdown options with enums. How can this be done?

Both the enum definition class(`Assignment`) and the class(`classOne`) using which  I am populating the page with controls are in the same `Namespace(MySolution.Data)`. While looping through classOne properties when the property name is 'SkillLevel' I will have to go to assignment class get the members of enum `SkillLevelEnum` and populate the dropdown.

Same needs to be done for other dropdowns also.

**My Code:**

```
namespace MySolution.Data
{
  public class classOne : MyAdapter
    {
        private string _Model;

        public string Model
        {
            get { return _Model; }
            set { _Model = value; }
        }

        private Assignement.SkillLevelEnum _SkillLevel;

        public Assignement.SkillLevelEnum SkillLevel
        {
            get { return _SkillLevel; }
            set { _SkillLevel = value; }
        }

        private Assignement.MinimalSkillsEnum _MinimalSkill;

        public Assignement.MinimalSkillsEnum MinimalSkill
        {
            get { return _MinimalSkill; }
            set { _MinimalSkill = value; }
        }

        public Assignemen.WorkLoadEnum WorkLoad
        {
            get { return _WorkLoad; }
            set { _WorkLoad = value; }
        }
    }

   public class Assignement : MyAdapter
     {

        #region Enumerations

        public enum SkillLevelEnum
        {
            LowerSkills = 0, HighestSkills = 1, Any = 2
        }

        public enum MinimalSkillsEnum
        {
            Accountable = 0,
            Responsible = 1,
            Expert = 2,
            Senior = 3,
            Medium = 4,
            Junior = 5
        }

        public enum WorkLoadEnum
        {
            LessBusy = 0, MostBusy = 1, Any = 2
        }

        #endregion
   }

}
```

Thanks

**Edit:**

I don't want to hardcode any of the property names. I am looping through the properties as below.

properties = Utility.GetAllPropertyForClass("className")

Panel panel = new Panel();
  panelMe.Controls.Add(panel);

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {

```
        if (!property.PropertyType.IsEnum)
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.ID = "txt" + i.ToString();                
            panel.Controls.Add(txt);  
        }
        else
        {
            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList();
            ddl.ID = "ddl" + i.ToString();

            // Here based on the property.name i need to get the enum members which is defined in a different class using reflection

            panel.Controls.Add(ddl);
        }        

        panel.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here are sample examples for how to bind enum with dropdown list

```
public enum ProgrammingLanguage
{
    CSharp,
    VB,
    JAVA
}
foreach (ProgrammingLanguage enmLnaguage  in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ProgrammingLanguage)))
{
     cboProgrammingLanguage.Items.Add(new ListItem(enmLnaguage.ToString(), Convert.ToInt32( enmLnaguage).ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var enumvalues=Enum.GetValues(typeof(MinimalSkillsEnum));
var enumNames=Enum.GetNames(typeof(MinimalSkillsEnum));
```

enumvalues will be an array and enumNames is a string array.

Answer (score 1):

If your enum is MinimalSkillsEnum, this should work:

```
string[] enumOptions = Enum.GetNames(typeof(MinimalSkillsEnum));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the labels of an Enum via the GetNames function

```
List<string> options = Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum));
```

You could then use that directly as the data source for your drop-down

```
MyDropDown.DataSource = options;
MyDropDown.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

to bind enum to dropdown check [How do you bind an Enum to a DropDownList control in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953/how-do-you-bind-an-enum-to-a-dropdownlist-control-in-asp-net)