# How can I get set of Enums except one using Linq?

Tags: c#

I have a set of enums

```
public enum SyncRequestTypeEnum
{
 ProjectLevel=1,
 DiffSync=2,
 FullSync=3
}
```

I want to display these enums in a drop down list except ProjectLevel.
Can I get these details using linq?
Can someone help on this?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953/how-do-you-bind-an-enum-to-a-dropdownlist-control-in-asp-net. Perhaps LINQ isn't necessary.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe something like this:

```
var result = Enum
        .GetValues(typeof(SyncRequestTypeEnum))
        .Cast<SyncRequestTypeEnum>()
        .Where(w =>w!=SyncRequestTypeEnum.ProjectLevel)
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Found myself in a similar situation where I needed the names of the Enum instead of their values.

To do that you could use this:

```
var exceptThese = new List<string> { nameof(SyncRequestTypeEnum.ProjectLevel) };
var result = Enum.GetNames<SyncRequestTypeEnum>().ToList().Except(exceptThese);
```