# How to bind enums to dropdown list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I used linq to get a set of Enums except one.This is my Linq

```
List<SyncRequestTypeEnum> lstDefaultSyncList = (List<SyncRequestTypeEnum>)(Enum
  .GetValues(typeof(SyncRequestTypeEnum))
  .Cast<SyncRequestTypeEnum>()
  .Except(new SyncRequestTypeEnum[] { SyncRequestTypeEnum.ProjectLevel })).ToList();
```

SyncRequestTypeEnum is my enum class which has 3 Enums.
 Here I am using `(Enum.GetValues(typeof(SyncRequestTypeEnum))` so I am getting values. Now I am binding these values to dropdownlist as:

```
 ((DropDownList)control).DataSource = HtmlEncodeHelper.HtmlEncode(lstDefaultSyncList );
 ((DropDownList)control).DataBind();
```

This is not binding the actual enums. In UI it is displaying the values as `System.Data.DataRowView`. If I use `GetNames` instead of `GetValues` it is throwing a cast error

can someone help on this?

Comment: Changed to answer below

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you bind an Enum to a DropDownList control in ASP.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61953/how-do-you-bind-an-enum-to-a-dropdownlist-control-in-asp-net)