# Simple WPF RadioButton Binding?

Tags: wpf, binding, radio-button

What is the simplest way to bind a group of 3 radiobuttons to a property of type int for values 1, 2, or 3?

Comment: Please look at the solution [Binding IsChecked property of RadioButton in WPF](http://pstaev.blogspot.com/2008/10/binding-ischecked-property-of.html), it works like a charm. The original problem has been fixed for WPF 4.0!

Comment: A better and more generic solution can be found in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/406798/414306

Answer (score 41, accepted):

#### Updated Answer with a Simpler Approach

Please see [my new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73130781/168179) posted on this same page for a completely different, and much simpler approach to solving this issue.  That new approach uses custom `IValueConverter` and `Binding` subclasses which let you go back to using a true `RadioButton` instead of a heavily-styled `ListBox`, as shown here.

Again, unless there are other benefits you'd personally gain when using a `ListBox` subclass, [the other approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73130781/168179) is what I now recommend.

#### Original Answer

Actually, using the converter like that breaks two-way binding, plus as I said above, you can't use that with enumerations either.  The better way to do this is with a simple style against a ListBox, like this:

Note: Contrary to what DrWPF.com stated in their example, do *not* put the ContentPresenter inside the RadioButton or else if you add an item with content such as a button or something else, you will not be able to set focus or interact with it.  This technique solves that.  Also, you need to handle the graying of the text as well as removing of margins on labels or else it will not render correctly.  This style handles both for you as well.

```xml
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonListItem" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" >

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>

            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">

                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" >

                    <RadioButton IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,4,0" />

                    <ContentPresenter
                        Content             = "{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"
                        ContentTemplate     = "{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                        ContentStringFormat = "{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentStringFormat}"
                        HorizontalAlignment = "{TemplateBinding Control.HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                        VerticalAlignment   = "{TemplateBinding Control.VerticalContentAlignment}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels = "{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />

                </DockPanel>

            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>

    </Setter>

</Style>

<Style x:Key="RadioButtonList" TargetType="ListBox">

    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>

    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background"      Value="Transparent" />

    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource RadioButtonListItem}" />

    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>

<Style x:Key="HorizontalRadioButtonList" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}" TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You now have the look and feel of radio buttons, but you can do two-way binding, and you can use an enumeration.  Here's how...

```xml
<ListBox Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SomeVal}"
    SelectedValuePath="Tag">

    <ListBoxItem Tag="{x:Static l:MyEnum.SomeOption}"     >Some option</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Tag="{x:Static l:MyEnum.SomeOtherOption}">Some other option</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Tag="{x:Static l:MyEnum.YetAnother}"     >Yet another option</ListBoxItem>

</ListBox>
```

Also, since we explicitly separated out the style that tragets the ListBoxItem rather than putting it inline, again as the other examples have shown, you can now create a new style off of it to customize things on a per-item basis such as spacing. (This will not work if you simply try to target ListBoxItem as the keyed style overrides generic control targets.)

Here's an example of putting a margin of 6 above and below each item. (Note how you have to explicitly apply the style via the ItemContainerStyle property and not simply targeting ListBoxItem in the ListBox's resource section for the reason stated above.)

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SpacedRadioButtonListItem" TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource RadioButtonListItem}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,6" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<ListBox Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonList}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource SpacedRadioButtonListItem}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SomeVal}"
    SelectedValuePath="Tag">

    <ListBoxItem Tag="{x:Static l:MyEnum.SomeOption}"     >Some option</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Tag="{x:Static l:MyEnum.SomeOtherOption}">Some other option</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem Tag="{x:Static l:MyEnum.YetAnother}"     >Ter another option</ListBoxItem>

</ListBox>
```

Comment: +1, but if that's `the simplest way to bind a group of 3 radiobuttons to a property of type int for values 1, 2, or 3`, it does not speak very well for WPF really. It's really beyond me why they make the simpliest of things so headscratchingly difficult and needlessly complex

Comment: This actually does a little more than just that as it styles a listbox, which is a single control, and that's why binding works so simply (once you get through the crazy set-up of it.)  But yes, I agree the RadioButton class definitely has some binding shortcomings.  Of course you could do it much simpler with code-behind, but this way here, you only have to do the styles and such once, then using it later is much easier.

Comment: OMG, simple? With all due respect to your answer and effort but calling this "simple style" is quite far fetched, no? Isn't the core idea and perceived advantage of WPF over Winforms better data binding? How a simple radio button (and radio button grouping) breaks binding after years of WPF being in the market is beyond my understanding. Shame on MS.

Comment: That's actually an unfair statement.  Take a look at the control template for a regular button using ShowMeTheTemplate for instance.  It is *far* from simple, yet its use, adding a Button tag is very simple.  You're peeking under the covers with what I'm doing here, but if you instead just add that to your resources section, then forget about it, it too will be simple.

Comment: Plus, think about what you're commenting on... disparate radio controls acting on a single value.  Multiple controls means multiple bindings.  This style makes a single control--and thus a single value--look like multiple controls.  That's why this is great.  Additionally, this can also be used to bind to an IEnumerable and dynamically create the items. Can't do that at all with a Radio Button.

Answer (score 101):

I came up with a simple solution.

I have a model.cs class with:

```
private int _isSuccess;
public int IsSuccess { get { return _isSuccess; } set { _isSuccess = value; } }
```

I have Window1.xaml.cs file with DataContext set to model.cs. The xaml contains the radiobuttons:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSuccess, Converter={StaticResource radioBoolToIntConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}" Content="one" />
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSuccess, Converter={StaticResource radioBoolToIntConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}" Content="two" />
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSuccess, Converter={StaticResource radioBoolToIntConverter}, ConverterParameter=3}" Content="three" />
```

Here is my converter:

```
public class RadioBoolToIntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int integer = (int)value;
        if (integer==int.Parse(parameter.ToString()))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return parameter;
    }
}
```

And of course, in Window1's resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:RadioBoolToIntConverter x:Key="radioBoolToIntConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: The issue with this converter is it doesn't work with enums as the parameter (your ToString() call dies.)  See my answer below.

Comment: You just need to change your converter to Parse the Enum

Comment: Again, that will not work for two-way binding.  The 'Convert Back' call will attempt to have multiple things set the values of the binding differently in which case you run into a race condition when one attempts to set the property IsSuccess to one value, and another attempts to set it to a different one.  That's the issue with this approach.  Sure, it's less code, but you still have separate controls all trying to change a single property. (Remember, when you select one radio button, it unselects another, hence two changes.)

Comment: @MarqueIV That problem is easily solved as can be seen in the first comment for the accepted answer of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum

Comment: Ok, that's a pretty neat trick!  I'll give you that!  I'll also give you a vote-up for the reference.  Still, the way above, while more verbose, does allow you to do other things as illustrated, so I'll leave that here.

Comment: One thing @user1151923... isn't the proper thing to return in that case 'Binding.DoNothing' and not 'DependencyProperty.UnsetValue'?

Comment: Much cleaner than accepted answer - exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: How to set the default value. That is to select the first radio button when the window is first displayed?

Comment: But, pretty please, no "if (true) return true; else return false;" constructs... :-)

Comment: I really prefer this version of it, Voted up!

Comment: this is not simple

Answer (score 54):

I am very surprised nobody came up with this kind of solution to bind it against bool array. It might not be the cleanest, but it can be used very easily:

```
private bool[] _modeArray = new bool[] { true, false, false};
public bool[] ModeArray
{
    get { return _modeArray ; }
}
public int SelectedMode
{
    get { return Array.IndexOf(_modeArray, true); }
}
```

in XAML:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Mode" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ModeArray[0], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="Mode" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ModeArray[1], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="Mode" IsChecked="{Binding Path=ModeArray[2], Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

NOTE: you don't need two-way binding if you don't want to one checked by default. TwoWay binding is the biggest con of this solution.

Pros:

- No need for code behind
- No need for extra class (IValue Converter)
- No need for extra enums
- doesn't require bizarre binding
- straightforward and easy to understand
- doesn't violate MVVM (heh, at least I hope so)

Comment: I'm surprised with that too. This solution is for those that are new to WPF, only know how to do binding and want a quick binding for radio buttons. It's very straightforward and simple. +1

Comment: This is nice, very quick to throw in & test before writing out my own `Converter`. +1

Comment: Just a small advice: Since C# 6 you won't need a backingfield anymore. Simply use the AutoProperty: public bool[] ModeArray { get; } = new bool[] { true, false, false };

Comment: How can this be data driven?  If I load values from a database how can I set an option programatically?

Comment: @RayBrennan this option is not really suited for dynamic data set (dont think it is possible in .xaml). If you need more complex use, I d suggest choosing one of the more complex solutions i.e. a converter (...or generate bidnings in codebehind).

Comment: Firstly, great soilution. I have one question since I'm new to WPF: how do i set this up where I can check which option is selected?

Comment: @mmangual83 Your question is rather ambiguous: if you mean how to set default value of radio group, you should set corresponding element of the `_modeArray` literal `true`(first one in the example). If you are asking how to preview default value in designer, answer is like any other other dabinding, through `d:DataContext`/`d:DesignInstance`.

Comment: @wondra what I mean to say is: say I choose a radio button from your ModeArray collection, then how would I set up a callback, or a method that listens when a radio button has been checked?

Comment: @mmangual83 ever figure that out?

Comment: @Julien if I understand you (both) correctly, you would like to run a piece of code on change. I dont think that is straightforward and I would suggest using converter instead - this is first and foremost quick and simple solution. Of course you could create property for each boolean or use a wrapper with INotify, but that is too complex in my opinion, for more feature rich solution I would choose the converter.

Answer (score 23):

I know it's way way overdue, but I have an alternative solution, which is lighter and simpler. Derive a class from `System.Windows.Controls.RadioButton` and declare two dependency properties `RadioValue` and  `RadioBinding`. Then in the class code, override `OnChecked` and set the `RadioBinding` property value to that of the `RadioValue` property value. In the other direction, trap changes to the `RadioBinding` property using a callback, and if the new value is equal to the value of the `RadioValue` property, set its `IsChecked` property to `true`.

Here's the code:

```
public class MyRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public object RadioValue
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(RadioValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadioValueProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RadioValue.
       This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadioValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "RadioValue", 
            typeof(object), 
            typeof(MyRadioButton), 
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object RadioBinding
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(RadioBindingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadioBindingProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for RadioBinding.
       This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadioBindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "RadioBinding", 
            typeof(object), 
            typeof(MyRadioButton), 
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                null, 
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, 
                OnRadioBindingChanged));

    private static void OnRadioBindingChanged(
        DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyRadioButton rb = (MyRadioButton)d;
        if (rb.RadioValue.Equals(e.NewValue))
            rb.SetCurrentValue(RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty, true);
    }

    protected override void OnChecked(RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnChecked(e);
        SetCurrentValue(RadioBindingProperty, RadioValue);
    }
}
```

XAML usage:

```
<my:MyRadioButton GroupName="grp1" Content="Value 1"
    RadioValue="val1" RadioBinding="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
<my:MyRadioButton GroupName="grp1" Content="Value 2"
    RadioValue="val2" RadioBinding="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
<my:MyRadioButton GroupName="grp1" Content="Value 3"
    RadioValue="val3" RadioBinding="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
<my:MyRadioButton GroupName="grp1" Content="Value 4"
    RadioValue="val4" RadioBinding="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
```

Hope someone finds this useful after all this time :)

Comment: A very nice solution, thanks for posting.  So much cleaner and easier to implement.

Comment: I certainly did. The ~ line 40 should read: 
            rb.SetCurrentValue(RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty, rb.RadioValue.Equals(e.NewValue));  So that no radioboxes are checked when the binding has some other value than the ones indicated. (Sorry about the formatting I can't seem to insert a newline).

Answer (score 5):

I've come up with solution using `Binding.DoNothing` returned from converter which doesn't break two-way binding.

```
public class EnumToCheckedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value.GetType() == Type)
        {
            try
            {
                var parameterFlag = Enum.Parse(Type, parameter as string);

                if (Equals(parameterFlag, value))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                return false;
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException();
            }

            return false;
        }
        else if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null && value is bool check)
        {
            if (check)
            {
                try
                {
                    return Enum.Parse(Type, parameter as string);
                }
                catch(ArgumentNullException)
                {
                    return Binding.DoNothing;
                }
                catch(ArgumentException)
                {
                    return Binding.DoNothing;
                }
            }

            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<converters:EnumToCheckedConverter x:Key="SourceConverter" Type="{x:Type monitor:VariableValueSource}" />
```

Radio button bindings:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="ValueSource" 
             IsChecked="{Binding Source, Converter={StaticResource SourceConverter}, ConverterParameter=Function}">Function</RadioButton>
```

Comment: This is pretty great (I wish it had IntelliSense support for enum values, though). FWIW, I've changed the `catch (ArgumentException)` bit to the following so the error in XAML is a bit clearer: `throw new NotSupportedException($"Enum {this.Type} doesn't contain value '{parameter}'.");`

Answer (score 3):

### Improved and Now-Recommended Answer (e.g. approach 2.0)

While I provided [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4120034/168179) to the question here on this page, as the commenters correctly call out, even though it's powerful and quite flexible, it's complexity is far from ideal when you just want to use simple `RadioButton` controls as-is.

As such, I've come up with a newer approach, shown below, that instead uses a custom `IValueConverter` and the power of `Binding.DoNothing` in it's `ConvertBack` method, the magic sauce that makes two-way bindings to `RadioButton` controls now work as one would expect.

### The RadioButtonValueConverter

Let's take a look at the converter itself:

```cs
public class RadioButtonValueConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter {

    public RadioButtonValueConverter(object optionValue)
        => OptionValue = optionValue;

    public object OptionValue { get; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => value.Equals(OptionValue);

    public object ConvertBack(object isChecked, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        => (bool)isChecked        // Is this the checked RadioButton? If so...
            ? OptionValue         // Send 'OptionValue' back to update the associated binding. Otherwise...
            : Binding.DoNothing;  // Return Binding.DoNothing, telling the binding 'ignore this change'

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        => this;
}
```

The magic sauce is in the use of `Binding.DoNothing` in the `ConvertBack` function.  Since with `RadioButton` controls, there can only be one active option per 'group' (i.e. only one with `IsChecked` set to `true`), we ensure only the specific `RadioButton` with that value is the only one whose binding updates the source.  Those on the other `RadioButton` instances simply do nothing.

Here's how you use it to bind to an `int` value as the OP asked (below, 'cv' is the imported namespace where the converter code resides, and the value you pass to the converter is the value that particular `RadioButton` represents)...

```xml
<RadioButton Content="One"   IsChecked="{Binding SomeIntProp, Converter={cv:RadioButtonValueConverter 1}}" />
<RadioButton Content="Two"   IsChecked="{Binding SomeIntProp, Converter={cv:RadioButtonValueConverter 2}}" />
<RadioButton Content="Three" IsChecked="{Binding SomeIntProp, Converter={cv:RadioButtonValueConverter 3}}" />
```

### Simplifying further with a custom `Binding` Subclass

While the above works, that's a lot of repeated code and for 90% of the time, you aren't doing anything special with the binding or converter. As such, let's try to simplify things with a `RadioButtonBinding` that sets up the converter for you.  Here's the code...

```cs
public class RadioButtonBinding : Binding {

    public RadioButtonBinding(string path, object optionValue)
    : base(path)
        => Converter = new RadioButtonValueConverter(optionValue);
}
```

With this new binding, the call site is greatly simplified (here, 'b' is the imported namespace where the binding code resides)...

```xml
<RadioButton Content="One"   IsChecked="{b:RadioButtonBinding SomeIntProp, 1}" />
<RadioButton Content="Two"   IsChecked="{b:RadioButtonBinding SomeIntProp, 2}" />
<RadioButton Content="Three" IsChecked="{b:RadioButtonBinding SomeIntProp, 3}" />
```

> *Note: Make sure you don't also set the Converter argument or you will defeat the entire point of using this!*

### Binding to Enum Values

The above example dealt with basic scalars (e.g. 1, 2, 3). However, what if the value we want to is an enumeration such as the following?

```cs
public enum TestEnum {
    yes,
    no,
    maybe,
    noIdea
}
```

The syntax is the same, but at the call-site, we need to be more specific about the value we're binding to making it much more verbose. (For instance, if you try and pass 'yes' by itself, it will be treated as a string, not an enum, so it will fail the equality check.)

Here's the converter version's call-site (here, 'v' is the imported namespace where the enum values reside)...

```xml
<RadioButton Content="Yes"     IsChecked="{Binding SomeEnumProp, Converter={cv:RadioButtonValueConverter {x:Static v:TestEnum.yes}}}" />
<RadioButton Content="No"      IsChecked="{Binding SomeEnumProp, Converter={cv:RadioButtonValueConverter {x:Static v:TestEnum.no}}}" />
<RadioButton Content="Maybe"   IsChecked="{Binding SomeEnumProp, Converter={cv:RadioButtonValueConverter {x:Static v:TestEnum.maybe}}}" />
<RadioButton Content="No Idea" IsChecked="{Binding SomeEnumProp, Converter={cv:RadioButtonValueConverter {x:Static v:TestEnum.noIdea}}}" />
```

And while simpler, here's the binding version's call-site, better, but still verbose...

```xml
<RadioButton Content="Yes"     IsChecked="{b:RadioButtonBinding SomeEnumProp, {x:Static v:TestEnum.yes}}" />
<RadioButton Content="No"      IsChecked="{b:RadioButtonBinding SomeEnumProp, {x:Static v:TestEnum.no}}" />
<RadioButton Content="Maybe"   IsChecked="{b:RadioButtonBinding SomeEnumProp, {x:Static v:TestEnum.maybe}}" />
<RadioButton Content="No Idea" IsChecked="{b:RadioButtonBinding SomeEnumProp, {x:Static v:TestEnum.noIdea}}" />
```

### Enum-Type-Specific Variants

If you know you will be binding to a particular enum type on many occasions, you can simplify the above by subclassing the earlier `RadioButtonValueConverter` and `RadioButtonBinding` to be enum-specific variants.

Below is doing exactly that with `TestEnum` defined above, like so...

```cs
// TestEnum-specific Converter
public class TestEnumConverter : RadioButtonValueConverter {

    public TestEnumConverter(TestEnum optionValue)
    : base(optionValue) {}
}

// TestEnum-specific Binding
public class TestEnumBinding : RadioButtonBinding {

    public TestEnumBinding(string path, TestEnum value)
    : base(path, value) { }
}
```

And here are the call sites...

```xml
<!- Converter Variants -->
<RadioButton Content="Yes"     IsChecked="{Binding SomeTestEnumProp, Converter={cv:TestEnumConverter yes}}" />
<RadioButton Content="No"      IsChecked="{Binding SomeTestEnumProp, Converter={cv:TestEnumConverter no}}" />
<RadioButton Content="Maybe"   IsChecked="{Binding SomeTestEnumProp, Converter={cv:TestEnumConverter maybe}}" />
<RadioButton Content="No Idea" IsChecked="{Binding SomeTestEnumProp, Converter={cv:TestEnumConverter noIdea}}" />

<!- Binding Variants -->
<RadioButton Content="Yes"     IsChecked="{b:TestEnumBinding SomeTestEnumProp, yes}" />
<RadioButton Content="No"      IsChecked="{b:TestEnumBinding SomeTestEnumProp, no}" />
<RadioButton Content="Maybe"   IsChecked="{b:TestEnumBinding SomeTestEnumProp, maybe}" />
<RadioButton Content="No Idea" IsChecked="{b:TestEnumBinding SomeTestEnumProp, noIdea}" />
```

As you can see, the XAML parser automatically handles the string-to-enum conversion for you making your code much easier to read.  Can't get much simpler than that! :)

*Sidenote: One nice thing about the versions where you explicitly specify the enum value in its more-verbose declaration is you get auto-completion for the enum's cases.  You don't get that with the enum-type-specific versions that convert the string for you.  However, the latter will fail to compile if you use an invalid string value so the tradeoff is brevity vs auto-complete convenience.*

Comment: I am confused why you provided what looks like a constructor called 'RadioButtonConverter' for a class called 'RadioButtonValueConverter'. Was that a typo or did I miss something?

Comment: Aaah! Good catch!  I was literally renaming it here in SO because it's a value converter, not a radio button converter, and I missed that manual rename.  Thanks!  Edited. :)

Comment: This is amazing. You can also use  ``ConverterParameter`` instead the ``OptionValue`` property (so you don't have to create a new converter every time)

Answer (score 2):

This example might be seem a bit lengthy, but its intention should be quite clear.

It uses 3 Boolean properties in the ViewModel called, `FlagForValue1`, `FlagForValue2` and `FlagForValue3`.
Each of these 3 properties is backed by a single private field called `_intValue`.

The 3 Radio buttons of the view (xaml) are each bound to its corresponding Flag property in the view model. This means the radio button displaying "Value 1" is bound to the `FlagForValue1` bool property in the view model and the other two accordingly.

When setting one of the properties in the view model (e.g. `FlagForValue1`), its important to also raise property changed events for the other two properties (e.g. `FlagForValue2`, and `FlagForValue3`) so the UI (WPF `INotifyPropertyChanged` infrastructure) can selected / deselect each radio button correctly.

```
    private int _intValue;

    public bool FlagForValue1
    {
        get
        {
            return (_intValue == 1) ? true : false;
        }
        set
        {
            _intValue = 1;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FlagForValue1");
            RaisePropertyChanged("FlagForValue2");
            RaisePropertyChanged("FlagForValue3");
        }
    }

    public bool FlagForValue2
    {
        get
        {
            return (_intValue == 2) ? true : false;
        }
        set
        {
            _intValue = 2;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FlagForValue1");
            RaisePropertyChanged("FlagForValue2");
            RaisePropertyChanged("FlagForValue3");
        }
    }

    public bool FlagForValue3
    {
        get
        {
            return (_intValue == 3) ? true : false;
        }
        set
        {
            _intValue = 3;
            RaisePropertyChanged("FlagForValue1");
            RaisePropertyChanged("FlagForValue2");
            RaisePropertyChanged("FlagForValue3");
        }
    }
```

The xaml looks like this:

```
                <RadioButton GroupName="Search" IsChecked="{Binding Path=FlagForValue1, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             >Value 1</RadioButton>

                <RadioButton GroupName="Search" IsChecked="{Binding Path=FlagForValue2, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             >Value 2</RadioButton>

                <RadioButton GroupName="Search" IsChecked="{Binding Path=FlagForValue3, Mode=TwoWay}"
                             >Value 3</RadioButton>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Comment: Ugly as sin, but that's basically what I do too.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it is possible to solve it in the model like this:
Suppose you have 3 boolean properties OptionA, OptionB, OptionC.

XAML:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding OptionA}"/>
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding OptionB}"/>
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding OptionC}"/>
```

CODE:

```
private bool _optionA;
public bool OptionA
{
    get { return _optionA; }
    set
    {
        _optionA = value;
        if( _optionA )
        {
             this.OptionB= false;
             this.OptionC = false;
        }
    }
}

private bool _optionB;
public bool OptionB
{
    get { return _optionB; }
    set
    {
        _optionB = value;
        if( _optionB )
        {
            this.OptionA= false;
            this.OptionC = false;
        }
    }
}

private bool _optionC;
public bool OptionC
{
    get { return _optionC; }
    set
    {
        _optionC = value;
        if( _optionC )
        {
            this.OptionA= false;
            this.OptionB = false;
        }
    }
}
```

You get the idea.
Not the cleanest thing, but easy.

Answer (score 1):

Aviad P.s answer works very well. However I had to change the equality check to compare strings in OnRadioBindingChanged otherwise the enum was compared to the string value and no radio button was checked initially.

```
    private static void OnRadioBindingChanged(
        DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        BindableRadioButton rb = (BindableRadioButton) d;
        if (rb.RadioValue.Equals(e.NewValue?.ToString()))
        {
            rb.SetCurrentValue(IsCheckedProperty, true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I created an attached property based on Aviad's Answer which doesn't require creating a new class

```
public static class RadioButtonHelper
{
    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(RadioButton))]
    public static object GetRadioValue(DependencyObject obj) => obj.GetValue(RadioValueProperty);
    public static void SetRadioValue(DependencyObject obj, object value) => obj.SetValue(RadioValueProperty, value);
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadioValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RadioValue", typeof(object), typeof(RadioButtonHelper), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnRadioValueChanged)));

    private static void OnRadioValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is RadioButton rb)
        {
            rb.Checked -= OnChecked;
            rb.Checked += OnChecked;
        }
    }

    public static void OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is RadioButton rb)
        {
            rb.SetCurrentValue(RadioBindingProperty, rb.GetValue(RadioValueProperty));
        }
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(RadioButton))]
    public static object GetRadioBinding(DependencyObject obj) => obj.GetValue(RadioBindingProperty);
    public static void SetRadioBinding(DependencyObject obj, object value) => obj.SetValue(RadioBindingProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadioBindingProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("RadioBinding", typeof(object), typeof(RadioButtonHelper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnRadioBindingChanged)));

    private static void OnRadioBindingChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is RadioButton rb && rb.GetValue(RadioValueProperty).Equals(e.NewValue))
        {
            rb.SetCurrentValue(RadioButton.IsCheckedProperty, true);
        }
    }
}
```

usage :

```
<RadioButton GroupName="grp1" Content="Value 1"
    helpers:RadioButtonHelper.RadioValue="val1" helpers:RadioButtonHelper.RadioBinding="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="grp1" Content="Value 2"
    helpers:RadioButtonHelper.RadioValue="val2" helpers:RadioButtonHelper.RadioBinding="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="grp1" Content="Value 3"
    helpers:RadioButtonHelper.RadioValue="val3" helpers:RadioButtonHelper.RadioBinding="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="grp1" Content="Value 4"
    helpers:RadioButtonHelper.RadioValue="val4" helpers:RadioButtonHelper.RadioBinding="{Binding SelectedValue}"/>
```