# RaisePropertyChanged sets back the value of the radio buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I got a strange behaviour if I want to update my UI by RaisePropertyChanged.
I use the 2nd solution (by Johnathan1) of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317891/simple-wpf-radiobutton-binding): I implemented the RadioBoolToIntConverter.

My VM looks like this:

```
public int myFilterRadioButtonInt
        {
            get
            {
                return _Filter.FilterMyProperty ? 1 : 2;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value == 1)
                    _Filter.FilterMyProperty = true;
                else if (value == 2)
                    _Filter.FilterMyProperty = false;
                else
                    return;

                RaisePropertyChanged("myFilterRadioButtonInt");
            }
        }
```

Converter looks like this (by Jonathan1 of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1317891/simple-wpf-radiobutton-binding)):

```
public class RadioBoolToIntConverter : IValueConverter

    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            int integer = (int)value;
            if (integer==int.Parse(parameter.ToString()))
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return parameter;
        }
    }
```

For understanding `_Filter.FilterMyProperty` is a bool value of the model which is responsible if my value which will be filtered is shown or is not shown. This is binded to 2 RadioButtons using the RadioBoolToIntConverter:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=myFilterRadioButtonInt, Converter={StaticResource RadioBoolToIntConverter}, ConverterParameter=1}">Show</RadioButton>
 <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=myFilterRadioButtonInt, Converter={StaticResource RadioBoolToIntConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}">Don't show</RadioButton>
```

Binding and toggling the RadioButtons is working properly.

The problem is if I set `_Filter.FilterMyProperty = true` by code (set a standard filter where this value should be filtered) and then do `RaisePropertyChanged("myFilterRadioButtonInt")` the `_Filter.FilterMyProperty` will be set to `false`.

**Edit:**

By `RaisePropertyChanged("myFilterRadioButtonInt")` (called by the setter of the Filter Property in the VM) the setter of `myFilterRadioButtonInt` is called again and it will set the current value of the RadioBox (in my case the `value` is `2` so the setter will set back the `_Filter.FilterMyProperty` to `false`.

It is not possible to change the value of the RadioBoxes by code with this method. I thought only the getter will be called when I call `RaisePropertyChanged("myFilterRadioButtonInt")`. 
How can I solve this problem and why is the setter being called by `RaisePropertyChanged("myFilterRadioButtonInt")`?

**Edit:**

Returning the parameter in ConvertBack() was the problem. Here is my solution:

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool val;
    if (!bool.TryParse(value.ToString(), out val))
        return 0;

    int iParam;
    if (!int.TryParse(parameter.ToString(), out iParam))
        return 0;

    return val ? iParam : 0;
}
```

Comment: RaisePropertyChanged("myFilterRadioButtonInt"); is not changing the value of _Filter.FilterMyProperty.   Post the converter.  I bet the converter is changing the value.

Comment: @Blam added the converter to the question.

Comment: normally only the getter is called, otherwise (if the setter was called) there would be some ***StackOverflow*** exception, there is obviously a call to `RaisePropertyChanged` in the setter. So I doubt there is still some other code triggering the setter, not the `RaisePropertyChanged()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you returning the parameter as the value

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    return parameter;
}
```

The first button is going to set the value to true every time and the second to false every time.

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    Bool vBool = Bool.Parse(value);
    Int iParam = IntParse(parameter);
    if(iParm > 2 || iParem < 0) return false;
    if(vBool) return iParam;
    else if (iParam == 2) return 1;
    else return 2;
}
```

Also on the set if the current value is correct you should return immediately and not call RaisePropertyChanged.

Comment: Returning the parameter was the problem. I added the solution to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [article](https://reformatcode.com/code/c/boolean-to-integer-converter-issue-when-set-from-viewmodel) which provides a consistent solution.  I tried the solution in the OP and it didn't work consistently for me -- I had random instances where the selected radio button was not correctly reflected.

The ConvertBack should be:

```
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(false) ? DependencyProperty.UnsetValue : parameter;
    }
```

Comment: You, good sir, is my hero! I thought I'd lose my mind over this, but your solution works perfectly!