# Noobie WPF namespace and converter problem

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, namespaces, converters

Please forgive the noob question but I'm going round in circles and need answers...

Anyway, I've been looking at this article [WPF: How to bind RadioButtons to an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/wpf-how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum) but I just can't get the convertor to be recognised within the XAML file.

```
<Window x:Class="Widget.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    Title="Widget" Height="366" Width="588" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <EnumBooleanConverter x:Key="enumBooleanConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
...
```

I have a seperate file holding the EnumBooleanConverter class but the above reference gives me the following error:

> Error 1 The tag 'EnumBooleanConverter' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'.

I've tried adding references to the assembly and then appending the tag to the XAML but to no avail.

```
<Window x:Class="Widget.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Widget;assembly=Widget"
    Title="Widget" Height="366" Width="588" WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:EnumBooleanConverter x:Key="enumBooleanConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After much head scratching (and a fair amount of shouting at the screen) I have identified the problem.

It turns out that identifying the namespace shouldn't have the assembly.

I was defining it like this

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Widget;assembly=Widget"
```

... But it should have just been like this

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Widget"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure EnumBooleanConverter is publicly accessible and it has a public empty constructor.

Comment: I thought this may have fixed the problem but when I did a rebuildI still get the error.