# Accessing the built-in styles in wpf

Tags: wpf, templates, button, styles

When I put button on a toolbar, its style changes automatically to match the toolbar elements.

I derived my own class from a ToggleButton, and now if I instantiate one on the toolbar, it looks like ordinary button again. How can I access the built-in templates of the WPF, such that I don't have to recreate the whole template from scratch?

Comment: Waht is the purpose of extending the ToggleButton class ? Do you change the template ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548863/how-can-i-prevent-a-togglebutton-from-being-toggled-without-setting-isenabled-fa
Currently I changed the template to change its appearance, but I would rather not do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the ToolBar has resources defined for some controls including `Button` and `ToggleButton`. This styles, you cand find them in ToolBar's metadata, are applied to each control of it's target type. So you can get the style and apply it yourself:

```
    <ToolBar>
        <my:CustomToggleButton 
            Height="100" Width="100" 
            Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}" 
            Content="Press me!" />
    </ToolBar>
```

If you have a lot of button's and don't want to set the style for each one you could set the style in codebehind of your custom control.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `style` on your custom toggle button like this to give it a look of Toolbar toggle button -

```
<local:LockableToggleButton LockToggle="True" Content="Test"
       Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access an change the template in the `OnApplyTemplate` override using the `VisualTreeHelper` and/ or `LogicalTreeHeler`.