# How can I create a set of ToggleButtons that behave like RadioButtons?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, radio-button, togglebutton

I am using C# and WPF and I basically want to have some toggle buttons and only one of them can be selected at the same time.

I found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362641/how-to-get-a-group-of-toggle-buttons-to-act-like-radio-buttons-in-wpf) about that, but the solution shown there does not work and I don't know why.

If I try to do it as mentioned in the question above, the `ItemTemplate` of the `ListBox` is not applied. I just don't get the toggle buttons into the listbox, instead it is shown as a "normal listbox".

My toggle button style looks like this, contained in one of my resource files:

```
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonListBox" TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
    <Setter Property="ListBox.ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ToggleButton Content="{Binding}"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ListBox.ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
</Style>
```

I would like to add the items directly in the XAML code, so my code for that would look something like

```
<ListBox Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonListBox}">
    <ListBoxItem>test1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>test2</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

How can I create such a set of buttons?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a group of toggle buttons to act like radio buttons in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362641/how-to-get-a-group-of-toggle-buttons-to-act-like-radio-buttons-in-wpf)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you want radio buttons that look like toggle buttons won't radio buttons styled to look like toggle buttons solve your problem?

```
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton GroupName="groupFoo" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">Button 1</RadioButton>
    <RadioButton GroupName="groupFoo" Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">Button 2</RadioButton>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: yeah i think that actually solved my problem. This is so much easier than i tried to do it. Even though I thought about it a short moment, i couldn't imagine it works that well and that easy. I will edit the solution into the question above. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Sören: That's one of the greatest things about WPF: behavior is separate from presentation. Also, it would be better to post the solution as an answer. After a while you can accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: i know, i tried to accept it and it did not work yet (3 min lock). Now it did. Thanks again!

Comment: the problem is that you cant uncheck

Comment: Unfortunately "x:Type ToggleButton" trick doesn't work anymore - I have VS 15.7.4 and .NET 4.7.2 and VS complains "resource "{x:Type ToggleButton}" could not be resolved"! Doh...