# WPF toggle panel visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, panel, visibility

I have two panels, only one should be visible at the same time. I change between them by clicking a button, one on each panel.

Is there a nice way to do this in xaml without codebehind or viewmodel?

Comment: The button on panel X should make the panel X *in*visible, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion with using a tabcontrol is good. I found some code which styles a TabControl to only show the TabItem content

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Grid>
    <TabControl BorderThickness="0" Padding="0">
      <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TabItem">
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </TabControl.Resources>
      <TabItem Header="Not shown">
        <Grid Background="Red"/>
      </TabItem>
      <TabItem>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">Tab 2

        </TextBlock>
      </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
  </Grid>
</P
```

Answer (score 3):

It's actually possible, however quite tricky.

My example works without any code-behind, actually without any value converters, too.

Here is the code: (now simplified version, thanks to @H.B. for ideas)

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Page.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="RBToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="RadioButton">
      <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
           <ControlTemplate>
              <ToggleButton
                 IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
           </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
       <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
       <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
       <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
       <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15"/>
       <Setter Property="Content" Value="Hide"/>
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="MyBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Page.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Green" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource MyBorderStyle}" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=greenB}">
      <RadioButton x:Name="greenB" GroupName="x" Style="{StaticResource RBToggleButtonStyle}"/>
    </Border>
    <Border Background="Red" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource MyBorderStyle}" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=redB}">
      <RadioButton x:Name="redB" GroupName="x" Style="{StaticResource RBToggleButtonStyle}"/>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

The idea of using `ToggleButtons` is stolen from [some other question at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362641/how-to-get-a-group-of-toggle-buttons-to-act-like-radio-buttons-in-wpf/5188053#5188053)

Comment: @H.B.: you cannot make the style for the toggle button common: the data trigger is bound each time to the opposite button (greenB and redB respectively)

Comment: Oh snap, move the triggers into an individual style, and base it on the control-template only style.

Comment: @H.B.: just added the corrected version: parametrized with DataContext

Comment: @Vlad: I meant my version (which i tested before i commited the edit).

Comment: @H.B.: Actually, the triggers are not needed, since we are using ToggleButtons. I'll remove them completely.

Answer (score 1):

If you used ToggleButtons, then you could bind the visibility of Panel 1 to the IsChecked state of Button 2, and the visibility of Panel 2 to the IsChecked state of Button 1. Make them TwoWay bindings and use the built-in BooleanToVisibility converter.

Comment: It's always been built-in. WPF was introduced in .NET 3.0 and so was BooleanToVisibilityConverter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the TabControl for this?

Comment: Nice suggestion, but not useful for this case

Comment: Or perhaps using a TabControl could be useful. Is it possible to move the tab button outside the header?

Answer (score 0):

A little work around with a [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) should do the trick. Sure it's not plain old XAML, but it's not in the codebehind and can be reuse.

I see something like binding X visibility to Y visibility and add a Converter to it :

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
  return (Visibility)value == Visibility.Visible ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so. You would need to use viewmodel or codebehind. Use a Style with a DataTrigger and bind the value of the visibility property to a property in viewmodel, avoiding the use of codebehind.

Comment: You are underestimating XAML.