# Toolbox design in MVVM application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, toolbox

I need to design a toolbox menu on top of my application that is shown below. Only one tool can be selected at any time so it is like radiobuttons.

What would be the most sensible way to implement this feature in an MVVM application?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using `ToggleButtons` for this (or rather Radio Buttons styled as ToggleButtons). You can find out how to do this on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362641/how-to-get-a-group-of-toggle-buttons-to-act-like-radio-buttons-in-wpf) (second answer, *not* the accepted one).