# ToggleButtons in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

I have two `ToggleButtons`. I want only one of them to be in the `Pressed` state at any time. So let's say `Model ToggleButton` is pressed:

I want to achieve the below concepts:

1. If I press `Drawing ToggleButton`, the `Model ToggleButton` will be unpressed and `Drawing ToggleButton` will go to pressed state.
2. If press the `Model Button` which is in the pressed state nothing will happen.

By the way here is all I have done so far :(

```
<ToggleButton Width="50" Height="23"  Margin="0 0 0 0">Model</ToggleButton>
<ToggleButton Width="50" Height="23"  Margin="0 0 7 0">Drawing</ToggleButton>
```

**Update:**

Using the provided link under the comments, I came up with this:

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="Model" IsChecked="True" />
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" Content="Drawing" />
```

Now the above code gives me two buttons, but how can I style these? I know how to style. But I don't know what to style here? I mean I have already filled the style property here how can I style the `ToggleButton` itself?

[image]

Comment: Looks like what you need is 2 radio buttons, if you don't like their apprearance, just change their templates.

Comment: @KingKing Oh you are right. Thanks for the wisdom.

Comment: also `RadioButton` inherits from `ToggleButton`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362641/how-to-get-a-group-of-toggle-buttons-to-act-like-radio-buttons-in-wpf

Comment: @Vahid - Answer with most upvotes in the link provided by DLeh will work for you.

Comment: @RohitVats Thanks, I was actually checking that answer, I updated the question.

Comment: What properties you want to set in Style? Are those properties common with RadioButton?

Comment: @RohitVats I want to change the shape/background of the `Button` in Normal and Pressed/Checked states.

Comment: @Vahid Background is easy, but Shape would mean creating a whole new Template for the button.

Comment: @Rachel Yeah I know how to style it I just didn't know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since ***RadioButton inherits from ToggleButton***, you can set ToggleButton style to it and ***use BasedOn to inherit default style of ToggleButton*** like this:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Test" Width="50" Height="23" Margin="0 0 7 0"
                Content="Model">
    <RadioButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            <!-- Set other properties here-->
        </Style>
    </RadioButton.Style>
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit. This is exactly what I needed to get started.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5287256/302677) that [DLeh linked in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24871561/togglebuttons-in-wpf#comment38629201_24871561), you can do this by styling a RadioButton to use the ToggleButton styles.

```
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" />
```

To answer your second question on how to customize the style property for this, you can create another style that inherits from the base ToggleButton style, and use it instead. Like this:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomToggleButtonStyle" 
       TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    // Custom Style setters here
</Style>

<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource CustomToggleButtonStyle}" />
```

And of course there's always the option of completely rewriting the entire template yourself from scratch. MSDN has a good examples of a [custom ToggleButton Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468212(v=vs.110).aspx) you could use to start with.

Comment: Thank you so much Rachel for the link. It helped me a lot.

Comment: @Vahid Np, I use that link a lot when creating my own templates, because there's actually a lot more than goes into a good template than just basic appearances :)