# Allow only one radio button to be checked in a WPF datagird

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid, ivalueconverter

My datagrid is bound to an observable collection, The datagrid has two columns - one for radio buttons, another to display names. 
At the moment, I am able to make multiple selections on the datagrid, But my requirement is to select only one radio button at a time such that the selected radio button should notify the viewmodel about the selected user name. 
How can i achieve it ?

Here's what I tried:

```
<DataGrid Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=panel}" 
                              ItemsSource="{Binding obvUsers}"                           
                              Height="390" >                                                                                                                                                                        
                        <DataGrid.Columns>                            
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="100">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding IsUserSelected}"                                    
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Name">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding UserName}" />
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>                
                        </DataGrid.Columns>                       
                    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a group of toggle buttons to act like radio buttons in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362641/how-to-get-a-group-of-toggle-buttons-to-act-like-radio-buttons-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put a `GroupName` for your `RadioButton`. All `RadioButton` in `DataGrid` should have a single selection because they have the same group.
This works for me.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="100">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <RadioButton GroupName="abc" IsChecked="{Binding IsUserSelected}">
            </RadioButton>                                    
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```