# How to "Choose one from multi toggle button" in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

I'm working on WPF Application. I have 3 Toggle Button in my application. I'm using Image in toggle button. I'm using this toggle buttons for choose screen mode(1 screen or 3 screen or 4 screen).

```
    <GroupBox >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ToggleButton  Height="50" Padding="10 5 10 5" Margin="5">
                <Image Source="content/1screen.png"/>
            </ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton  Height="50" Padding="10 5 10 5" Margin="5">
                <Image Source="content/3screen.png"/>
            </ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton  Height="50" Padding="10 5 10 5" Margin="5">
                <Image Source="content/4screen.png"/>
            </ToggleButton>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
```

So I have to choose just one of them. For example: if i choose 3 screen toggle button, than i choose 4 screen toggle button, the 3 screen toggle button have to be unchecked. Is there a anyone to help me?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2364872/9363973) answer might help you out

Comment: @MindSwipe i try this way. it works. But i'm searching best way. Thank you.

Comment: And if you're looking for an easier solution [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5287256/9363973) answer on the same question is raelly easy

Comment: @MindSwipe Thank you very much! İ try this and its clearly work!

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to just use RadioButtons but style them like ToggleButtons like so:

```xml
<RadioButton Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" />
```

This creates a RadioButton but applies the styling from ToggleButton, so you can do whatever you can with RadioButtons but it will look like a ToggleButton. To then be able to only choose one, yo can use the `GroupName` property as explained [here](https://www.wpftutorial.net/RadioButton.html)