# WPF XAML in XAML, referencing external UserControls?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

New to WPF, trying to move back and forth between various `UserControl`s that I've made.

They're defined in separate files, say `f1.xaml` `f2` `f3` `f4`, and then I made a `master` view.

Can I import `f1` and/or `f2` into `master`, and then use them with some logic to move between them (https://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/switching-between-viewsusercontrols-using-mvvm/)?  In that article, the `DataTemplate`s are all inlined.

Is my initial assumption flawed, and I actually need to inline all my views into one massive file?

If I can use external files, how do I import an external XAML UserControl into another XAML?

<del>Tutorial links welcome!</del>
*Edit, post-solve*

Posting a couple other tutorial links that helped me out:

- [xaml what is "local:"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399997/xaml-what-is-local)
- https://wpftutorial.net/DataTemplates.html
- https://wpftutorial.net/ListBoxDataTemplate.html
- https://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/07/06/wpf-applying-data-templates-dynamically-in-contentcontrol/ (outdated but helpful)

Comment: Yes, you can - and the Wordpress article you linked to explains how with a demonstration too. Why do you think you need to ask here?

Comment: @Dai - cheers, thanks - yes, it shows how to switch between them, but I'm confused how to get them coordinated into the same place.  Do I import them or add a `ResourceDictionary` or something?

Comment: You don't need to "import" or "include" them, just name them as XAML elements using the typenames you gave them, e.g. `<Window> <StackPanel> <local:MyUserControlF1 /> </StackPanel> </Window>`. Note you'll need an XML namespace prefix, often `local:`  or some other value you declared in your `xmlns`.

Comment: Oh cool! Sounds like that's what I was missing, maybe.  Going to try now.

Comment: @Dai - Yep, that worked, thank you - I can accept as a solution if you want to write up? Also interested in what that concept is called, I'm not sure of the terminology surrounding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to "import" or "include" them, just name them as XAML elements using the typenames you gave them.

For example:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YourUserControlNamespace"
>
    <StackPanel>
        <local:MyUserControlF1 />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Note you'll need an XML namespace prefix, often `local:` or some other value you declared in your `xmlns`