# Unable to find enum type for static reference in WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, enums, valueconverter

I'm trying to bind an enum to a radio button in WPF (Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/wpf-how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum/2908885#2908885)), but I have trouble finding the enum type for the converter parameter:

The enum is defined in the following way

```
namespace Application.Models
{
    public class Enums
    {
        public enum MySelections { one, two ,three };

        public MySelections CurrentSelection;

        ...

    }
}
```

I am trying to bind now the checkbox like this (The data context is assumed to be correct and the value converter implemented:)

```
<Window x:Class="Application.MainWindow"
        ....
        xnlns:models="clr-namespace:Application.Models" >

...
<RadioButton Content="One"
             IsChecked="{Binding Path=CurrentSelection, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static models:Enums.MySelections.one}}" />
...
```

The problem lies with `{x:Static models:Enums.MySelections.one}` which constantly throws the error that the type `models:Enums.MySelections` could not be found.

How can I find my enum type?

Comment: does it work if you move the enum definition up into the namespace and remove the `Enum` class from the bind?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use "+" instead of "." to get to a nested type in XAML:

```
{x:Static models:Enums+MySelections.one}
```

Comment: Except that in VS2010 at least that causes the designer to be unable to load the view, so then you can't even see what you are trying to design.

Comment: +1 - Works for me.  However, it doesn't seem to work with x:Type.  Does x:Type not support this syntax?  (e.g. {x:Type models:Enums+MySelections})

Comment: Great! This should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 17):

You could declare it outside of your class:

```
namespace Application.Models
{
    public enum MySelections { one, two, three };

    public  class Enums
    {
        public MySelections CurrentSelection;
```

And then this xaml will work:

```
.... ConverterParameter={x:Static models:MySelections.one}
```

---

The [`x:Static`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135.aspx) markup has the fixed syntax:

> {x:Static
>   prefix:typeName.staticMemberName}

Comment: That was it, thank you. So just to clarify, where is this enum residing now? A static member of a namespace?