# Binding a constant to a radiobutton IsChecked commandparameter

Tags: wpf, binding

I am trying to do the same thing as it is done here:

[Unable to find enum type for static reference in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676649/unable-to-find-enum-type-for-static-reference-in-wpf)

but instead of enums I have some string constants:

```
namespace MyProject.XYZ
{
     public class MyConstants
     {
          public const string AAA = "Type AAA";
          public const string BBB = "Type BBB";
          public const string CCC = "Type CCC";
          ...
     }
}
```

I have a couple of radio buttons that look like this:

```
...
xmlns:myConstants="clr-namespace:MyProject.XYZ"
...


<RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=CurrentSelection, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static myConstants:MyConstants
.AAA}}" />
...
```

But i get an error in regards with the command parameter:
'myConstants:MyConstants.AAA' member is not valid because it does not have a qualifying type name.

I've done it with enums and it works, but the application that I am working on heavily relies on these constants.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is a bit late but for somebody else could this be a usefull solution:

Define the class like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <local:MyConstants xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject.XYZ" x:Key="MyConstants"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And the Binding like this:

```
{Binding Path=CurrentSelection, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource MyConstants}}
```