# WPF Bind to list of different types

Tags: c#, wpf

I am running into an interesting challenge related to WPF Data Binding.

I have a form where I want to show a few different options.  I am using radio buttons and showing these four items is working great:
Not Selected | No Agreement | Joint Custody | Sole Custody

In the case that Sole Custody is selected, I have a combo box with a list of parents in it and the user picks the parent.  This is also working find.

Now, I want to change things so that the "Sole Custody" radio button does not show and, instead, the list of parents are shown as radio buttons, that way I have something like:
Not Selected | No Agreement | Joint Custody | Bob Smith | Jane Doe

I am having a hard time figuring out how to make this happen.  Does any body have any examples?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891924/wpf-mvvm-radio-buttons-on-itemscontrol, they use a listbox with an radiobutton per row.

Comment: Not clear what is the question, please try to localize the problem and ask only the stuff that does not work

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to make it. I would  mention the most two reasonable solutions for me.

1. You should create a collection which includes all possible selections ( Not Selected | No Agreement | Joint Custody | Bob Smith | Jane Doe )
2. Create MultiValueConverter that takes (Not Selected | No Agreement | Joint Custody) and parent names and returns a combined collection

Than, put a ListBox in xaml without any UI ( as proposed by ganchito55 ) and bind the collection to ListBox.