# Getting the value of the selected Radiobutton

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have two radio buttons, in the same group name, users selects either one (by default none is checked). When the user selects either one a string variable should store the content of the radio button. How to achieve this?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145606/how-can-i-reduce-this-wpf-boilerplate-code/9145914#9145914) might help, bind the `SelectedItem` to some property.

Comment: It might if i actually understand!! i am new and so having tough time to get my head around simple answer would be nice tks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First double click on the radiobutton(s) to get their checked events
Then inside the eventhandler write this

```
<RadioButton Content="foo" Checked="radioButton1_Checked" />
<RadioButton Content="bar" Checked="radioButton1_Checked"/>

private void radioButton1_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   variable = (string)(sender as RadioButton).Content;
}
```

Comment: i guess you mean just "Click" instead of Double Click

Comment: You could probably use the event routing and handle Checked only on the parent container.

Comment: @H.B. hi, would like to know is there anything wrong with the below code?  public void radio_button_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          Object  variable = (string)(sender as RadioButton).Content;
        }

Comment: I tried to add Object and change to public rather than private and the thing i do this is because i want to use the variable in a button_click method. How to do that?

Comment: @JackyBoi: Introduce a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx) (and/or [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)) and assign to that.

Comment: @H.B. dont need for that i have resolved it and can you please answer the question so that i can mark yours right! tks