# Bind radio buttons to enum in a specific list of objects

Tags: c#, wpf, enums, radio-button

i have got the following situation:

- I have a list of objects (`List<MyObjects>`).
- The Class `MyObjects` contains an enum called `States` and some other Properties like `ObjectName`:

  ```
  public enum States { State1, State2, State3, State4, State5 }
  public string ObjectName { get; set; }
  // some more Properties
  ```

  and a private field and a property like this:

  ```
  private States _state = States.State1; // State1 is the default state

  public States State
  {
    get { return _state; }
    set
    {
      if (_state != value)
      {
        _state = value;  
        OnPropertyChanged("State");
      }
    }
  }
  ```
- In my XAML I want to display the list of `MyObjects` in a ListView and five Radio Buttons for each state of my enum. I do this as follows:

  ```
  <ListView x:Name="myObjectsListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjectList}">
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ObjectName}"
                         Header="Object Name"
                         Width="Auto"/>
         <!-- some more GridViewColumns -->
       </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
  <StackPanel>
      <RadioButton x:Name="state1RB"
          Content="{x:Static States.State1}"
          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=myObjectsListView, Path=SelectedItem.State,
              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
              Converter={StaticResource enumToBool},
              ConverterParameter={x:Static States.State1},
              Mode=TwoWay}"/>

      <RadioButton x:Name="state2RB"
          Content="{x:Static States.State2}"
          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=myObjectsListView, Path=SelectedItem.State,
              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
              Converter={StaticResource enumToBool},
              ConverterParameter={x:Static States.State2},
              Mode=TwoWay}"/>

      <RadioButton x:Name="state3RB"
          Content="{x:Static States.State3}"
          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=myObjectsListView, Path=SelectedItem.State,
              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
              Converter={StaticResource enumToBool},
              ConverterParameter={x:Static States.State3},
              Mode=TwoWay}"/>


      <RadioButton x:Name="state4RB"
          Content="{x:Static States.State4}"
          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=myObjectsListView, Path=SelectedItem.State,
              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
              Converter={StaticResource enumToBool},
              ConverterParameter={x:Static States.State4},
              Mode=TwoWay}"/>

      <RadioButton x:Name="state5RB"
          Content="{x:Static States.State5}"
          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=myObjectsListView, Path=SelectedItem.State,
              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
              Converter={StaticResource enumToBool},
              ConverterParameter={x:Static States.State5},
              Mode=TwoWay}"/>
  </StackPanel>
  ```
- I'm using an EnumToBoolean Converter which looks like this:

  ```
  [ValueConversion(typeof(System.Enum), typeof(bool))]
  public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
       return value.Equals (parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
      if ((Boolean)value)
        return parameter;
      return null;
    }
  }
  ```

The binding works, the display of the radio button works but the problem is when i check another Radio Button for the first element in the ListView, the
`State` is saved correctly. When i now change the selected item in the ListView and then select the first item in the ListView again, no Radio Button is checked, because the getter of the `State` property doesn't get called.

I was searching for a solution but my specific problem is, that i have a list of `MyObjects` which contains a state and on changing the selected item, the selected radio button should also be changed.

I hope someone understand my problem and can help.

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: You might be interested in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145606/) as your code is rather redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9145914/1384848) answer to solve my problem. It just worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works, I've re-created it all in a fresh project and it correctly updates the radio button to reflect the up to date value when you change the SelectedItem (i.e. after changing the selection to non-default).

I think you have something else in the project which is interfering and you should try taking out pieces of the solution and testing them out in isolation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVVM, I have found a good approach to be using an ICommand to  update the SelectedItem in the view model.  The XAML would look like this.

```
    <RadioButton x:Name="state5RB"
    Content="{x:Static States.State5}"
    Command="{Binding UpdateSelectedItemCommand}"
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=State,
        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
        Converter={StaticResource enumToBool},
        ConverterParameter={x:Static States.State5},
        Mode=TwoWay}">
       <RadioButton.CommandParameter>
           <myEnum:State>State5</myEnum:State>          
       </RadioButton.CommandParameter>

   </RadioButton>
```

The ViewModel would look something like this:

```
ICommand UpdateSelectedItemCommand {get;set;}

..

UpdateSelectedItemCommand = new DelegateCommand( (param) =>
{
   State= (States) param;
});
```

Replace DelegateCommand with your custom object that implements ICommand.