# strange focus rectangles on wpf radiobutton

Tags: wpf, xaml, radio-button

Why does the rectangle appear in the radio buttons when one of them is clicked.

[image: strange focus rectangles on wpf radiobutton]

the XAML markup is given below

```
<RadioButton GroupName="LabelDisp" IsChecked=".. Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter= LabOnly}" Content="{x:Static resx:StringRes.RadioButtonLab}" Style="{StaticResource ListOption}" Command="{Binding Path=Command}"></RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="LabelDisp" IsChecked=".. Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter= DescOnly}" Content="{x:Static resx:StringRes.RadioButtonDesc}" Style="{StaticResource ListOption}" Command="{Binding Path=Command}"></RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="LabelDisp" IsChecked=".. Converter={StaticResource enumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter= LabAndDescr}" Content="{x:Static resx:StringRes.RadioButtonBoth}" Style="{StaticResource ListOption}" Command="{Binding Path=Command}"></RadioButton>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I was returning null should have returned Binding.Donothing instead.

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
            {
                return (bool)value ? Enum.Parse(targetType, parameter.ToString(), true) : Binding.DoNothing;
            }
```

Comment: Boolean.DoNothing...great answer!

Answer (score 5):

Those are called FocusVisualStyle, you can remove it -

```
<RadioButton FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"/>
```

**Update**

Yeah H.B. is right, i thought you was talking about dotted border we got on clicking radioButton. But it seems a `validation border`, check your converter code, something is breaking in it.

Comment: +1 While not the answer to this question, everybody should know how to disable FocusVisuals, since they can be difficult to find if you don't know what to look for.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a validation error to me, possibly because of the spaces at the front of the `ConverterParameter`. (You might want to consider using [another method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145606/how-can-i-reduce-radiobutton-binding-code/9145914#9145914) for binding RadioButtons)

Comment: @TrustyCoder: So? It's still a validation error, no matter where it comes from (it should be the converter throwing an exception in this case)

Comment: @TrustyCoder, @H.B. was talking about the space in this block: `ConverterParameter= LabOnly`.  This is passing in a string like this: `" LabOnly"`, which might be marking it as invalid for whatever reason.

Comment: no that is not the reason i guess. when i removed the converter expression its fine. so i am assuming something is wrong with the enum to boolean converter.

Comment: @TrustyCoder: Huh? That's what i just said. Also the converter could possibly be fine but if you pass in a string with a space it might throw an exception. Also as i said: Don't use a converter in the first place, see the link in my answer.

Comment: I have two enum and two group radio. But one validation error and one success while everything same ( WTF )