# How to find out which button is selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<GroupBox x:Name="groupBox" Header="Operating System" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="74" Width="280">
        <StackPanel>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Os" Content="Windows 7 (64-bit)" IsChecked="True"/>
            <RadioButton GroupName="Os" Content="Windows 7 (32-bit)" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
```

I have several radio button groups in my application

How can I access which one has been checked in the Code-Behind using C#?

Is it absolutely necessary to use **x:Name=** on each RadioButton or is there a better way?

Code samples always appreciated

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9145606/546730

Comment: that example is about ListBox

Comment: No, you don't understand. The ListBox simply serves the purpose of keeping track of the selection for you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! There is a better way, its called *binding*. Outside of binding, you are pretty much stuck (I can imagine handling all the checked events separately, and assigning to an enum, but is that really *better*?)

For radio buttons, you would typically use an `enum` to represent all the possible values:

```
public enum OsTypes
{
    Windows7_32,
    Windows7_64
}
```

And then bind each of your radio buttons to a global "selected" property on your VM. You need a [`ValueEqualsConverter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2908885/1783619) for this:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
```

And then your radio buttons look like:

```
<RadioButton Content="Windows 7 32-bit"
             IsChecked= "{Binding CurrentOs, 
                         Converter={StaticResource ValueEqualsConverter},
                         ConverterParameter={x:Static local:OsTypes.Windows7_32}}"
```

Of course, you have a property in your VM:

```
public OsTypes CurrentOs {get; set;}
```

No x:Name, complicated switch statements, or anything else. Nice, clean, and well designed. MVVM *works* with WPF, use it!

Comment: do I need a different class to manage the radio button? I am very new to MVVM

Comment: @softwareisfun I'm not sure what you mean, but I don't think so. You need a data context (view model) which is the only piece I didn't provide the full code for. If you are having basic issues with MVVM, feel free to join me in the WPF chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf

Comment: I would just have a bool for each radio button and skip a converter requirement, but I can see how using Enum's is nice

Comment: @Julien When it's a true *radio button* (only one selected at a time), the Enum model is *far* more convenient in my opinion.