# Example Using Radio Buttons on Form

Tags: wpf, workflow-foundation-4, activitydesigner

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF: How to bind RadioButtons to an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/wpf-how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum)

I am new to using WF4 designer and am looking for a simple visual example of using radio buttons on a form. My basic requirements are that a user be able to select Option 1, 2, or 3, and depending on their selection, show a corresponding alert. I have been experimenting with Flowchart and Switch but with no luck yet. Thank you.

Comment: I think you have to clarify a little bit the question.

Comment: I've created a flowchart that contains a form on it with 3 radio buttons, Options 1, 2, and 3. The output arguments for each radio button are set as Boolean. There is also a button on the form which when clicked should, based on which radio button is selected, pop up the appropriate alert, for example, "Option 1 selected". Please let me know if I can provide any more detail.

Comment: You should have the options be an enum `public enum Options { One, Two, Three }` and then bind the radio buttons to a public property of the enum type.  There are plenty of questions about how to bind an enumeration to radio buttons, such [as this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/wpf-how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum).