# Identifying the Checked RadioButton without having to test each RadioButton

Tags: wpf

I have a long collection of RadioButtons in a group. I keep track of which one currently IsChecked = True by  assigning the name of the button to an appropriately scoped string variable. I assign the value of this string from the Checked/Unchecked event for each RadioButton in the group.

Though this seems to work, I wonder if there isn't a more elegant (if not correct) way to quickly identify the "checked" RadioButton in a group without having to test each RadioButton every time.

Michael

Comment: what do you mean you 'test each radiobutton everytime'?

Comment: you can bind your radio buttons to enum like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum