# Binding radio button to enum property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, enums, radio-button

I think I've followed the examples given in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2908885/3245111) but my property is not changing when button are changed.  Any suggestions on where I went wrong?

C# code for enum and class

```
public enum SystemTypes
{
    TypeA,
    TypeB
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    SystemTypes systemType = SystemTypes.TypeA;
    public SystemTypes SystemType 
    {
        get { return systemType; }
        set { systemType = value; }
    }
}

public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

xaml

```
        <Canvas>
            <Canvas.Resources>
                <local:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="EnumToBooleanConverter" />
            </Canvas.Resources>
            <RadioButton x:Name="TypeARadioButton" Content="TypeA" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" 
                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=SystemType, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SystemTypes.TypeA}}" />
            <RadioButton x:Name="TypeBRadioButton" Content="TypeB" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="31"
                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=SystemType, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SystemTypes.TypeB}}" />

        </Canvas>
```

Comment: You didn't set DataContext for the window so it can't find `SystemType` property to bind to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set Binding Mode to TwoWay, then in Converter implement method ConvertBack responsible for converting bool to SystemTypes, in settter of SystemType include

```
set { systemType = value; OnPropertyChanged(() => "SystemType");}
```

in order to fill property in that its value was changed.

```
OnPropertyChanged(() => "SystemType")
```

can work if you implement interface INotifyPropertyChanged. I cannot you whether you set DataContext, if you did not binding is not working. In order to rectify this after InitializeComponent() add

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the Converter code.  I edited the question to show that class also, I had also tried two way.  The code you specified won't compile because the lambda expression is not a delegate type, but I don't think it matters because the setter is never being called.