# [.net 4.5]How to Binding enum to RadioButton ?Why x:static not support enum?

Tags: enums, binding

When I need to binding a enum to RadioButton , Reference the [How to bind RadioButtons to an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum) question's better answer.

enum code:

```
public enum SelectionMode
{
    FixedMode = 0,
    FreeMode = 1
}

/// <summary>
/// MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

xaml code:

```
<RadioButton Content="FreeMode" IsChecked="{Binding ChannelSelectionMode, Converter={StaticResource enumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SelectionMode.FreeMode}}" ></RadioButton>
```

I've got this exception :

> xaml exception: namaspace not found the SelectionMode, the enum
>   SelectionMode in the namespace,  x:Type Local:SelectionMode can be
>   work.

I tried this way:

1. move enum `SelectionMode` to `Viewmodels`'s namespace.
2. move enum `SelectionMode` into one `Viewmodel` class.

but all not work.
Please give me some sugguestion, I am crazy.

Comment: Where is your converter code?

Answer (score 0):

The post you shared has converter code or you can find here in this post as well. 
[Binding radio button to enum property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25414802/binding-radio-button-to-enum-property).

Also you need to add another radio button something like this

```
<RadioButton Content="FixedMode" IsChecked="{Binding ChannelSelectionMode, Converter={StaticResource enumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SelectionMode.FixedMode}}" ></RadioButton>
<RadioButton Content="FreeMode" IsChecked="{Binding ChannelSelectionMode, Converter={StaticResource enumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:SelectionMode.FreeMode}}" ></RadioButton>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in the moming I rebuild once agin. It works, eh....Most time restart VS would be a good way. [Laugh and cry]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a problem, don't worry, restart VS, leave for a while and then come back