# Ensure only one CheckBox Checked at a time

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, mvvm

I have WPF data grid which contain two rows with checkboxes:

```
  <Grid>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
       <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <DataGrid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
               Name="dsGrid"
               AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" >
       <DataGrid.Columns>     
         <DataGridTextColumn Header="Properties Name" MinWidth="150" Binding="{Binding Propertie}" />     
                 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Server " MinWidth="150" >
                     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <StackPanel>
                                 <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                 <TextBlock Name="PropertiesTextBlock" 
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                            Text="{Binding Server}"
                                            Grid.Column="1"/>
                                 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding                                       Path=IsServerSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                           Checked="Server_Checked" 
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                                           Visibility="{Binding Equal,
                                           Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility},FallbackValue=Hidden}" 
                                           Grid.Column="0"/>
                                </Grid>     
                             </StackPanel>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn>     
                 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header=" Local " MinWidth="150">
                     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <StackPanel>
                                 <Grid>
                                     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                     <TextBlock Name="PropertiesTextBlock" 
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                                                Text="{Binding Local}" 
                                                Grid.Column="1"/>
                                     <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsLocalSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                               Checked="Local_Checked" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               Visibility="{Binding Equal, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility},FallbackValue=Hidden}"       Grid.Column="0"></CheckBox>
                                 </Grid>
                             </StackPanel>
                         </DataTemplate>
                     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 </DataGridTemplateColumn>     
             </DataGrid.Columns>
         </DataGrid>
         <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"  Name="Entities_List"
                  SelectionChanged="Entities_List_SelectionChanged"
                  SelectionMode="Single"
                  Grid.Column="0"/>
         <Button Content="Merge"
                 Name="Merge_Button"
                 Click="Merge_Button_Click"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                 Grid.Column="0"  />
     </Grid>
```

DataContext ViewModel:

```
public string Server { get; set; }
public string Local { get; set; }    
private bool _pIsServerSelected;
private bool _pIsLocalSelected;

public bool IsLocalSelected
{
    get
    {
        return _pIsLocalSelected;
    }
    set
    {
        _pIsLocalSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }
}

public bool IsServerSelected
{
    get
    {
        return _pIsServerSelected;
    }
    set
    {
        _pIsServerSelected = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
    }
}
```

My needs are to ensure, that only one Checkbox is checked at a time.
So if the ServerCheckBox gets checked I want to uncheck the LocalCheckBox.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting in your question. You would benefit from reading the ["*How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?*"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) help page for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got everything you need:

```
    public bool IsLocalSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return pIsLocalSelected;
        }
        set //LocalSelected is Set: -> UnSet Server
        {
            pIsLocalSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsLocalSelected");
            IsServerSelected = false;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsServerSelected");
        }
    }

    public bool IsServerSelected
    {
        get
        {
            return pIsServerSelected;
        }
        set //ServerSelected is Set: -> UnSet Local
        {
            pIsServerSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsServerSelected");
            IsLocalSelected = false;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsLocalSelected");
        }
    }
```

This will do the trick.

> **BUT this will create an infinity loop...**

In order to get this problem solved the easiest way I would recommend using `RadioButton` instead of `CheckBox`.
If the Local is selected the server will be unselected and vise versa.

Comment: I have infantry loop if I added this changes.

Comment: Sure, i should have seen this coming. I strongly reccomend you to use radiobuttons instead.

Comment: I still have StackOverflowException (( @Fe De

Comment: Just use the RadioButtons and you wont need to disable the other one anymore.

Comment: I use RadioButtons . Maybe problem here :
IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsLocalSelected, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
? @ Fe De

Comment: have you removed the IsLocalSelected = false;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsLocalSelected"); from both setters ?

Comment: From both? From IsServerSelected @Fe De

Comment: a need check or unchecked Radio Buttons vise versa all time.

Comment: You dont need to uncheck anything. Its radio buttons and there can only be one checked at a time ... you only need to use the {get;}

Comment: I don't understand what i need change... 
For now when i removed IsLocalSelected=false , when I click on Local radio button when Server Radiobutton already checked , Server become unchecked . But vice versa not working.

Comment: your datacontext needs to look like we had it in your question make it same as there.

Comment: Here is fixed my problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26681749/c-sharp-wpf-uncheck-checkboxes