# RadioButtons binding on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, radio-button, windows-phone-8.1

I have some problem with binding my `RadioButton` property `IsChecked`. I have two `RadioButton`'s on the grid, which `Visibility` binded to a property on my viewmodel. What i want to achieve is to always setting first `RadioButton` to Checked state, when grid is become visible.
Here is some code:

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                <RadioButton Grid.Row="0"
                             Margin="20,0" 
                             IsChecked="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource StateToBooleanConverter}}"
                             Content="content 1" />

                <RadioButton Grid.Row="1"
                             Margin="20,0"
                             Content="content 2" />


            </Grid>
```

Following my logic it should set first `RadioButton` as Checked when property `State` is going to specific state, when grid is become visible. And its working fine until i hit second `RadioButton`. Then my binding is not working and when `State` is changing nothing happens in my `StateToBooleanConverter`. 
I read a lot of information about problems with binding in radiobuttons, but nothing worked in my case.
Is it possible do it without new property for checking radioButton? I would be appreciated for any advise how i can fix this issue.

Edit:

There is some code from viewmodel and Converter for `IsChecked`:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel
    {
        this.ChangeState = new RelayCommand(this.ChangeStateExecute);
    }

    public PageState State
    {
        get
        {
            return this.state;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.state != value)
            {
                this.state = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand ChangeState { get; private set; }

    private void ChangeStateExecute()
    {
        this.State = PageState.RadioButtonsVisible;
    }
}

public class StateToBooleanConverter : Converter
{
    protected override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var state = (PageState)value;
        var result = state == PageState.RadioButtonsVisible;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include your cs code.

Comment: Does `State` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: @mike-eason yes, it does.

Comment: @lloyd check my post, i added some code

Comment: how does working base.RaisePropertyChanged(); ??

Comment: @ali-yousefie I am using MvvmLight

Comment: Since I cant see all of your code it's hard to say. I would try setting the UpdateSourceTrigger property in your binding to PropertyChanged. Also you need to set the mode to two way or your radios wont work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that PageState is an enum, [this answer is what you're looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406798/1141853)

All of the radio buttons that you want to group together all bind to the same property of the ViewModel and all use the same ValueConverter.  The value that triggers a radio button check / uncheck is passed into the ValueConverter's `parameter` property.

For your specific problem, the `EnumBooleanConverter` can be directly copy-pasted into your code (be sure to read though it and make sure you understand it).

The XAML then becomes

```
<Grid Visibility="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource VisibilityConverter}}">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <RadioButton Grid.Row="0"
                         Margin="20,0" 
                         IsChecked="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=RadioButtonVisible}"
                         Content="content 1" />

            <RadioButton Grid.Row="1"
                         Margin="20,0"
                         IsChecked="{Binding State, Converter={StaticResource EnumBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter=*Insert enum value here*}"
                         Content="content 2" />


        </Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you. You was almost there! With little improvement i got what i want.