# Binding RadioButton to Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, enums, radio-button

Problem:
Binding a property of type Enum to RadioButtons, using parameterized Converter. No exception thrown, Radiobutton might have validation problems (not sure). Red box around RadioButtons is shown when testing.

Info:
Was trying to use the solution given in
[How to bind RadioButtons to an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum#_=_)

I've got an Enum like this:

```
namespace crmVerwaltungstools.Models
{
   public enum CrmSystemType
   {
     Training = 0,
     Live = 1
   }
}
```

BooleanToEnumConverter:

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? (CrmSystemType)parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
```

and inside my Window:

```
xmlns:models="clr-namespace:crmVerwaltungstool.Models"

     <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
          <StackPanel.Resources>
                <converter:RadioButtonIsCheckedToCrmSystemTypeConverter x:Key="RbIsCheckedToCrmSystemTypeConverter" />
          </StackPanel.Resources>

          <RadioButton Content="Schulungs-System" GroupName="rbg_SelectSystem"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=SystemType, Converter={StaticResource RbIsCheckedToCrmSystemTypeConverter},
                                 ConverterParameter={x:Static models:CrmSystemType.Training}}"/>
          <RadioButton Content="Live-System" GroupName="rbg_SelectSystem"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=SystemType, Converter={StaticResource RbIsCheckedToCrmSystemTypeConverter},
                                 ConverterParameter={x:Static models:CrmSystemType.Live}}"/>
      </StackPanel>
```

Can't see any mistakes. (Maybe just saw too much lines of code today...)

Thanks for helping!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

I found a little piece of older code inside my viewmodel where i tried to define my enum as an internal class.

So, basically, my programm was confused which enum to use - the internal class inside the viewmodel or the external class inside the models folder.

After i removed the internal enum, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check in your converter that value isn't null:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return value.Equals(parameter);
    }
```

Do that also in ConvertBack method.

Second, write your xaml something like that:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>          
        <local:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="EnumToBooleanConverter" />          
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=YourEnumProperty, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:YourEnumType.Enum1}}" />
    <RadioButton IsChecked="{Binding Path=YourEnumProperty, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:YourEnumType.Enum2}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Good morning,

still having that problem.

Added the `value==null` check. While testing, never saw that it becomes 'true'. Maybe because the default-value of an Enum is the value at index[0] of that enum, in my case the default value would be 'Training'.

Actually the `Stackpanel.Resources`part is already existing, forgot to put in the code of my question.
I will edit my question and add that missing part.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You mean `CrmSystemType`?
That is a Enum-Type created by myself for choosing  to which of our Crm-Server i want to connect. Live- or Training-Server.

Comment: That's the name of my Property.
`private CrmSystemType systemType`
        `public CrmSystemType SystemType
        {
            get { return systemType; }
            set { systemType = value; OnPropertyChanged("SystemType"); }
        }`

Comment: Ok, in a seperate project for testing explicitly this function it is working very well.
Like in the solution i mentioned under "Info".
So there must be some problems inside of my code.
Well, now i have to digg inside of my code for it xD

But thanks for helping.