# Strange thing about RadioButton in the WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've found a strange thing about RadioButton in the WPF.
I can put radio button to one component and select another component at the same time. Like on the screenshot.

How can I fix that?

If I don't select any component like in the second string, then next code give me an error:

```
MessageBox.Show(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting a `ListBoxItem`, and setting the `Checked` property of a `RadioButton` are two *totally different actions*.

Thus, you can check one radio button, and have a different list box item selected. If you don't have any list box items selected, trying to access `SelectedItem` will throw as you have found.

The basic answer is that you probably don't want to select the list box items. Set the `SelectionMode` to `None`. To find the checked radio button, consider using a [`ValueEqualsConverter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2908885/1783619)