# Enable field of a Listbox from combobox (C#-xaml)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox, listbox

I would like to enable or disable a field when a specific value in the combobox is selected:

In my xaml, I have a `ListBox` (ListToTransfert)wich is filled by dragging items from another `Listbox` (ListViewContents).

The ListToTransfert got 3 fields: `Name`, `Gap`and `Time`.
The field `Name`cannot be edited while the 2 others can be.

When the combobox has its value changed to `Gap`or to `Time`, I want the appropriate column to be `enabled` while the other one is `disabled`.

Here is the code of my XAML:

```
     <!--    ListViewContents  -->

        <Label Content="Contents" Background="White" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,16,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="31"/>
        <ListView Background="#bdc3c7" x:Name="ListViewContents" SelectionMode="Single" Margin="11,51.826,0,11" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="400">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView >
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TransferContent}"  
                        CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListViewContents}" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Label Content="Label" Height="100" Width="100"/>
        </ListView>

     <!--    ListToTransfert  -->
     <TextBox Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.TextBoxStyleKey}}" 
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="851,16,0,0" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="31" Text="{Binding groupName}" />

            <ListView Background="#bdc3c7" x:Name="ListToTransfert" ItemsSource="{Binding ContentsToTransfer}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="400" Margin="0,51.826,21,11">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Amount" >
                            <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Background="AliceBlue" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>

                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="A" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Gap"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Time"></GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>

                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                        <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DeleteContent}"  
                            CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=ListToTransfert}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            </ListView>
```

My combobox is not yet created since i'm not sure if there is a solution for this problem, tho there is always one.

Can you propose me a XAML solution to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done either via a group of `RadioButton`s or a single `ComboBox`.

### RadioButton

If you don't need to control this behavior from the view model, you can use the following :

```
<RadioButton x:Name="TimeRadioButton" Content="Time" />

<GridViewColumn Header="Gap">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=GapRadioButton}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

---

Alternatively, you can add `EnableGapColumn`/`EnableTimeColumn` on your view model. However, it would be better if you create an enum to define this behavior :

```
public enum TransfertViewType
{
    Gap, Time
}
```

And change your bindings with [`EnumToBooleanConverter`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum/2908885#2908885):

```
<!-- put this in a resource -->
<converter:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="EnumToBooleanConverter" />

<RadioButton Content="Time" IsChecked="{Binding ViewType, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static vm:YourViewModel.TransfertViewType}}"/>

<TextBlock IsEnabled="{Binding ViewType, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static vm:YourViewModel.TransfertViewType}}"/>
```

### ComboBox

It would pretty much the same as the second part of RadioButton section, except that you will need to create an `IEnumerable<TransfertViewType>` as the `ItemsSource` for the `ComboBox`. Or, an `IDictionary<TransfertViewType, string>` if you like to customize the description a little bit.

```
<!-- for ienumerable -->
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TransfertViewTypes}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ViewType}" />

<!-- for idictionary -->
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding TransfertViewTypes}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value" SelectedValuePath="Key"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ViewType}" />
```