# ToggleButton bound to Enum, how do you prevent toggling off?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, binding, enums

I have a group of ribbon toggle buttons inside of the same container in my XAML like this:

```
<ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Layouts">
    <ribbon:RibbonToggleButton Label="One"
        IsChecked="{Binding PaneManager.Layout,
                            Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter},
                            ConverterParameter={s:Static windows:Layouts.One}}"/>
    <ribbon:RibbonToggleButton Label="Two Vertical"
        IsChecked="{Binding PaneManager.Layout,
                            Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter},
                            ConverterParameter={s:Static windows:Layouts.TwoVertical}}"/>
    <!-- etc. for 2 horizontal and 4 panes -->
</ribbon:RibbonGroup>
```

I'm using the same EnumToBooleanConverter outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2908885/476048):

```
public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

The problem is that when a user clicks the toggle button that's *already selected*, the toggle button happily turns itself off--even though the bound value matches that toggle button.  When tracing through the code, what happens is that the `ConvertBack` method is called and it returns `Binding.DoNothing`.  Afterwards, `Convert` is not called to reassign the value.  When `ConvertBack` returns a value (i.e. it is clicked a second time and `IsChecked` is true again), the `Convert` method is called to reassign the value.

If I change the return type on false to be `DependencyObject.UnsetValue`, the toggle button is still turned off but now it has a red outline.

**How do I force WPF to re-evaluate the bound value so that the toggle button stays on?**

Comment: What is the data type of `PaneManager.Layout`? the `ConvertBack` should return a valid value of that data type.

Comment: Rule #1: Always define `..Parameter` first. Regarding problem: you can't use single parameter converter, because you need to pass **current** value of enum to convert `IsChecked` back (I assume you are using `[Flag]` enum). I'd use command and one-way converter myself. You may decide to use MultiValueConverter.

Comment: @KingKing  It's an application specific `enum`.  When toggling between the toggle buttons the converter supplied works like a charm.

Comment: @Sinatr It's not a [Flag] enum.  Just a standard mutually exclusive value.  I'm not experiencing any issues with the `CoonverterParameter` being defined second.  Command seems so over-architected since everything that needs to be done is handled in the DependencyProperty changed callback.

Comment: I thought you want to toggle bits. You are using `HasFlag` for unknown reasons, it could be a simple check `(Enum)value == (Enum)parameter`. `PaneManager.Layout` don't have to be a `DependencyProperty`, `IsChecked` can be bound to a normal property.

Comment: I fixed the code to what we have (using .Equals).  I copy pasted the snippet from the other answer.  And yes, I know it can be a normal property, but this is what we have since the binding is two way by design.

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems I have to control whether the toggle button `IsHitTestVisible` to make it behave properly.  If I change my toggle buttons to look like this:

```
<ribbon:RibbonGroup Header="Layouts">
    <ribbon:RibbonToggleButton Label="One"
        IsChecked="{Binding PaneManager.Layout,
                            Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter},
                            ConverterParameter={s:Static windows:Layouts.One}}"
        IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsChecked,
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                   Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"/>

    <ribbon:RibbonToggleButton Label="Two Vertical"
        IsChecked="{Binding PaneManager.Layout,
                            Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter},
                            ConverterParameter={s:Static windows:Layouts.TwoVertical}}"
        IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsChecked,
                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                   Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"/>
    <!-- etc. for 2 horizontal and 4 panes -->
</ribbon:RibbonGroup>
```

And then supply the following converter:

```
public class InverseBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return !(bool)value;
    }
}
```

It feels like a hack, but it does prevent toggling back off.  I am seriously open to more elegant solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy solution to prevent the user toggeling off the button is to handle the PreviewMouseDown and set the Handled property true when the related button is currently checked.

```
private void tbn_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ToggleButton clickedbtn = sender as ToggleButton;
    if (clickedbtn == null)
         return;

    if (clickedbtn.IsChecked.HasValue)
         e.Handled = clickedbtn.IsChecked.Value;
}
```

and in XAML:

```
<ToggleButton Name="tbnCustom" 
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=Type, 
        Converter={StaticResource enumToBooleanConverter}, 
        ConverterParameter={x:Static data:WorkDayType.Custom}}"
    PreviewMouseDown="tbn_PreviewMouseDown">Anders</ToggleButton>
```

hth