# Dynamically binding to an Enum

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I want to have an Enum on my ViewModel, let's say to represent a person's Gender. The View representing that ViewModel should be able to present a way of supplying that value; whether that is a group of Radio Buttons or a Combo Box (if there are lots). And there are plenty of examples out there where you hard-code Radio Buttons in the XAML each one saying which value it represents. And the better ones will also use the Display Attribute's Name to provide the text for the radio button.

I'm looking to go a step further. I'd like it to *generate* the RadioButtons dynamically based on the Enum's values and things like the DisplayAttribute's Name and Description. Ideally, I'd like it to choose to create a ComboBox (rather than RadioButtons) if it's more than 6 items (perhaps implemented as a Control of some sort); but let's see if we can walk before we try to run.  :)

My googling has got me pretty close... here's what I've got:

```
public enum Gender
{
    [Display(Name="Gentleman", Description = "Slugs and snails and puppy-dogs' tails")]
    Male,

    [Display(Name = "Lady", Description = "Sugar and spice and all things nice")]
    Female
}
```

Window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:EnumMultiConverter x:Key="EnumMultiConverter"/>

    <ObjectDataProvider
        MethodName="GetValues"
        ObjectType="{x:Type local:EnumDescriptionProvider}"
        x:Key="AdvancedGenderTypeEnum">

        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type TypeName="local:Gender"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AdvancedGenderTypeEnum}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding GroupName}" Content="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Description}">
                    <RadioButton.IsChecked>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EnumMultiConverter}" Mode="TwoWay">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}" Path="DataContext.Gender" Mode="TwoWay" />
                            <Binding Path="Value" Mode="OneWay"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </RadioButton.IsChecked>
                </RadioButton>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

EnumDescriptionProvider:

```
public static class EnumDescriptionProvider
{
    public static IList<EnumerationItem> GetValues(Type enumType)
    {
        string typeName = enumType.Name;
        var typeList = new List<EnumerationItem>();

        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        {
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = enumType.GetField(value.ToString());
            var displayAttribute = (DisplayAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fieldInfo, typeof(DisplayAttribute));

            if (displayAttribute == null)
            {
                typeList.Add(new EnumerationItem
                {
                    GroupName = typeName,
                    Value = value,
                    Name = value.ToString(),
                    Description = value.ToString()
                });
            }
            else
            {
                typeList.Add(new EnumerationItem
                {
                    GroupName = typeName,
                    Value = value,
                    Name = displayAttribute.Name,
                    Description = displayAttribute.Description
                });
            }
        }

        return typeList;
    }
}
```

EnumerationItem:

```
public class EnumerationItem
{
    public object GroupName { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And the MultiConverter (because IValueConverter can't take a Binding for the ConverterParameter):

```
public class EnumMultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0].Equals(values[1]);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

So the only problem I've got is that I can't do the ConvertBack. But maybe someone out there has a brilliant solution. As I say, ideally, I would just want some magical control that I can Bind to the Enum on my ViewModel, and for it to dynamically create RadioButtons for each value for that enum. But I'll take any suggestions that I can get.

Comment: Why do you want to use an Enum when a dictionary will do the task equally well, enums are used when we have compile time constants.

In your case ```Dictionary<string,DisplayAttribute>``` Will do just as well

Comment: Strike the above I misread the question

Comment: Why do you want to convert back? You already have the index - just bind the selected index to the view model and you can cast the index (an int) to the enum.

Comment: @code4life It's a two-way binding, so I would need the converter to work both ways.   Yes, I could add something else to my ViewModel, but I shouldn't have to change my view model because of the way I've implemented the view. Also, if I have 5 enums, that means I need to add 5 extra properties. The accepted solution shows how simple the XAML _should_ be, and it doesn't require the viewmodel to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a few years since I posted my other answer, so I thought I should post the benefit of my experience of taking that approach, and a newer, better solution.

I definitely had the right idea of wanting to have a single control to represent the collection of `RadioButton`s (for example, so that you could trivially swap back and forth between having a set of radio buttons, or a `ComboBox`. However, it was a mistake in my other answer to cram the generation of the items into that control. It's far more WPF-y to allow the user of the control to bind whatever they like into your control. (It also caused threading issues when I reached the point of wanting to tinker with which values were shown at a particular time.)

This new solution seems much cleaner, although it is (by necessity) made up of quite a few parts; but it does achieve that goal of having a single control to represent a collection of radio buttons. For example, you will be able to do:

```
<local:EnumRadioButtons SelectedValue="{Binding Gender, Mode=TwoWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Genders}"/>
```

where the ViewModel has...

```
    public ObservableCollection<IEnumerationItem> Genders { get; }

    public Gender? Gender
    {
        get => _gender;
        set => SetProperty(ref _gender, value); // common implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged, as seen on ViewModels.
    }
```

So settle in, and I'll walk you through it... and apologies if I'm teaching you to suck eggs.

The control itself is basically an extension of an `ItemsControl`, which gives it the ability to contain a collection of other controls. It allows you to control the overall layout of the individual items (e.g. if you want them sideways instead of vertically) in the same way that you would with an ItemsControl (via the `ItemsPanel`).

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

public class EnumRadioButtons : ItemsControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedValue), typeof(object), typeof(EnumRadioButtons));

    public object SelectedValue
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

We will need to set up the default styling of that; but I'll come back to that later. Let's take a look at the individual `EnumRadioButton` control. The biggest problem here is the same one posed in my original question... that converters cannot take a `ConverterParameter` via a `Binding`. This means I can't leave it up to the caller, so I need to know what type the collection of items is. So I've defined this interface to represent each item...

```
public interface IEnumerationItem
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    object Value { get; set; }

    string Description { get; set; }

    bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

and here's an example implementation...

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// I'm making the assumption that although the values can be set at any time, they will not be changed after these items are bound,
// so there is no need for this class to implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
[DebuggerDisplay("Name={Name}")]
public class EnumerationItem : IEnumerationItem
{
    public object Value { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

Clearly it would be useful to have something to help you create these things, so here is the interface...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public interface IEnumerationItemProvider
{
    IList<IEnumerationItem> GetValues(Type enumType);
}
```

and implementation...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Reflection;

internal class EnumerationItemProvider : IEnumerationItemProvider
{
    public IList<IEnumerationItem> GetValues(Type enumType)
    {
        var result = new List<IEnumerationItem>();

        foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(enumType))
        {
            var item = new EnumerationItem { Value = value };

            FieldInfo fieldInfo = enumType.GetField(value.ToString());

            var obsoleteAttribute = (ObsoleteAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fieldInfo, typeof(ObsoleteAttribute));
            item.IsEnabled = obsoleteAttribute == null;

            var displayAttribute = (DisplayAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fieldInfo, typeof(DisplayAttribute));
            item.Name = displayAttribute?.Name ?? value.ToString();
            item.Description = displayAttribute?.Description ?? value.ToString();

            result.Add(item);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The idea is that this would give you the starting point, and you could tinker with the items and their properties (if you need to) *before* you put them into an `ObservableCollection` and bind it to `EnumRadioButtons.ItemsSource`. After that point, you can add/remove items to/from the collection; but changing the properties will not be reflected (because I haven't made it implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, because I don't expect to need to change them after that). I think that's reasonable; but you can change the implementation if you disagree.

So, back to the individual `EnumRadioButton`. Basically it is just a `RadioButton`, which will set up the Binding when the `DataContext` is set. As I mentioned before we **have** to do it this way this because the `ConverterParameter` can't be a `Binding`, and a `MultiConverter` won't be able to `ConvertBack` to one of its sources.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class EnumRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IValueConverter> ConverterFactory = new Lazy<IValueConverter>(() => new EnumToBooleanConverter());

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);
        if (e.Property == DataContextProperty)
        {
            SetupBindings();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This entire method would not be necessary if I could have used a Binding for "ConverterParameter" - I could have done it all in XAML.
    /// </summary>
    private void SetupBindings()
    {
        var enumerationItem = DataContext as IEnumerationItem;
        if (enumerationItem != null)
        {
            // I'm making the assumption that the properties of an IEnumerationItem won't change after this point
            Content = enumerationItem.Name;
            IsEnabled = enumerationItem.IsEnabled;
            ToolTip = enumerationItem.Description;
            //// Note to self, I used to expose GroupName on IEnumerationItem, so that I could set that property here; but there is actually no need...
            //// You can have two EnumRadioButtons controls next to each other, bound to the same collection of values, each with SelectedItem bound
            //// to different properties, and they work independently without setting GroupName.

            var binding = new Binding
            {
                Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(EnumRadioButtons), 1),
                Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(EnumRadioButtons.SelectedValue)),
                Converter = ConverterFactory.Value, // because we can reuse the same instance for everything rather than having one for each individual value
                ConverterParameter = enumerationItem.Value,
            };

            SetBinding(IsCheckedProperty, binding);
        }
    }
}
```

As you've seen above, we're still going to need a Converter, and you've probably already got one like this; but for completeness, here it is...

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value?.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

The only thing left is to set up the default styling for those controls. (Note that if you already have default styles defined for `RadioButton` and `ItemsControl`, then you will want to add the `BasedOn` clause.)

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="EnumRadioButtonItem" DataType="{x:Type local:EnumerationItem}">
            <local:EnumRadioButton/>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style TargetType="local:EnumRadioButton">
            <!-- Put your preferred stylings in here -->
        </Style>

        <Style TargetType="local:EnumRadioButtons">
            <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="ItemTemplate" Value="{StaticResource EnumRadioButtonItem}"/>
            <!-- Put your preferred stylings in here -->
        </Style>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you use a custom behaviour, which will enable you to put all the Enum to ViewModel logic into a single reusable piece of code. That way you don't have to wrangle complex ValueConverters

There is a great article and GitHub sample that demonstrates a solution to this very problem, see the link below

[WPF – Enum ItemsSource With Custom Behavior - Article](http://deanchalk.com/wpf-enum-itemssource-with-custom-behavior/)

[GitHub repository for sample code](https://github.com/deanchalk/WPFEnumItemsSource)

I hope that gives  you what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks for your solution; however, it just creates a ListBox with an item for each value. I'm looking for something that gives me a usable *RadioButton* for each value. For example, if I remove the "ItemsControl.ItemTemplate" tag and its contents from what I've posted above, I'd have similar to what your solution provides (if I used the same "cheat" of adding a ToString method on my EnumerationItem).

Comment: You said you really wanted a combobox. Just change listbox for combobox and it works exactly the same

Comment: Apologies for the misunderstanding, let me clarify... it is a long-standing user interface design principle that you would use RadioButtons if there are only a few items (I think Microsoft have 6 as a limit); but if there are more than that, you should use a ComboBox.  I want something that will give me RadioButtons or a ComboBox depending on how many items there are.

Comment: Failing that, I definitely want something to create RadioButtons dynamically; because I can use my EnumDescriptionProvider as the ItemsSource for a ComboBox if I know there are going to be lots of values.  I'm in a scenario where the Enum values are likely to change, and I don't want to have to do screen re-designs just because the number of items in an Enum has changed.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, the key is the realization that a RadioButton's `Command` event always gets fired when the user clicks on it, even when the `IsChecked` property is bound. All you need to do is make your `IsChecked` multi-value binding `OneWay` and add a command handler that gets invoked when the radio button is checked by the user, i.e. something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <RadioButton Content="{Binding Name}" ToolTip="{Binding Description}"
                 Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}, Path=DataContext.CheckedCommand}"
                 CommandParameter="{Binding}">
        <RadioButton.IsChecked>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EnumMultiConverter}" Mode="OneWay">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}" Path="DataContext.Gender" />
                <Binding Path="Value" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </RadioButton.IsChecked>
    </RadioButton>
</DataTemplate>
```

Then back in your view model you provide a handler for the command which sets the value of Gender manually rather than relying on the radio buttons to propagate the value back themselves:

```
    public ICommand CheckedCommand { get { return new RelayCommand<Gender>(value => this.Gender = value); } }
```

Note that you don't even need a GroupName, it's all handled automatically according to which property and command you bind to in the view model (which is better for testing purposes anyway).

Comment: Thanks for that. Nice solution. good tip about GroupName for this approach. (BTW CommandParameter needs to be "{Binding Value}" because Binding is the EnumerationItem). Best answer so far. I just feel that my View ought to be able to bind two-way to an enum on the viewmodel. (i.e. I shouldn't need to change the view model to support the way the view has been implemented; and have to add a command for each Enum). That's why I'm thinking I might need to write my own control (I have no idea how to do that).

Comment: I would expect that you could do the same thing with an attached behaviour which you could then apply to all radio buttons automatically with a global style. Might even give it a go myself when I'm back at work next week.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found this post: [How to bind RadioButtons to an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum)
and if you look a long, long way down to the answer by [artiom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797249/artiom), he proposes a solution, and gives a link (which is now broken) before being chastised for giving a link that could become broken :)    I contacted him, and he instantly sent me the information. For example, it allows me to just have this in the XAML:

```
    <local:EnumRadioButton
        SelectedItem="{Binding Path=Gender, Mode=TwoWay}"
        EnumType="{x:Type local:Gender}"
        RadioButtonStyle="{StaticResource MyStyle}"/>
```

So rather than the MultiConverter that I mentioned in the original post, you need:

```
public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value?.Equals(parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

and here is the magic bit:

```
public class EnumRadioButton : ItemsControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnumTypeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(EnumType), typeof(Type), typeof(EnumRadioButton), new PropertyMetadata(null, EnumTypeChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(SelectedItem), typeof(object), typeof(EnumRadioButton));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadioButtonStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(RadioButtonStyle), typeof(Style), typeof(EnumRadioButton));


    public Type EnumType
    {
        get { return (Type)GetValue(EnumTypeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnumTypeProperty, value); }
    }

    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    public Style RadioButtonStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(RadioButtonStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RadioButtonStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void EnumTypeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        EnumRadioButton enumRadioButton = (EnumRadioButton)d;
        enumRadioButton.UpdateItems(e.NewValue as Type);
    }

    private void UpdateItems(Type newValue)
    {
        Items.Clear();
        if (!newValue.IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(newValue), $"Only enum types are supported in {GetType().Name} control");
        }

        var enumerationItems = EnumerationItemProvider.GetValues(newValue);
        foreach (var enumerationItem in enumerationItems)
        {
            var radioButton = new RadioButton { Content = enumerationItem.Name, ToolTip = enumerationItem.Description };
            SetCheckedBinding(enumerationItem, radioButton);
            SetStyleBinding(radioButton);
            Items.Add(radioButton);
        }
    }

    private void SetStyleBinding(RadioButton radioButton)
    {
        var binding = new Binding
        {
            Source = this,
            Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
            Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(RadioButtonStyle))
        };
        radioButton.SetBinding(StyleProperty, binding);
    }

    private void SetCheckedBinding(EnumerationItem enumerationItem, RadioButton radioButton)
    {
        var binding = new Binding
        {
            Source = this,
            Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
            Path = new PropertyPath(nameof(SelectedItem)),
            Converter = new EnumToBooleanConverter(), // would be more efficient as a singleton
            ConverterParameter = enumerationItem.Value
        };
        radioButton.SetBinding(ToggleButton.IsCheckedProperty, binding);
    }
}
```