# How to programmatically add buttons to a window after Instantiation à la Revit API's TaskDialog class

Tags: c#, wpf, button, enums, revit-api

I apologize if the question isn't as accurate to what I want, but I'm fairly new to coding any type of window/form without a visual element or robust IDE (currently don't have access to Visual Studio, but want to begin work on a GUI while I wait as I have a bulk of the driving code done). I've had a difficult time finding out if/how this is possible due to the wording of my queries so far being too similar to other topics, like enabling/disabling buttons.

What I want is to emulate the programmatic functionality of adding buttons to a window present in the Revit API TaskDialog class. For those unfamiliar, this is a sample of how one creates a TaskDialog with a basic message and two buttons in C#:

```cs
TaskDialog dialog = new TaskDialog("Sample");
dialog.MainContent = "This is an example of how a TaskDialog is coded in the Revit API";
dialog.CommonButtons = TaskDialogCommonButtons.OK | TaskDialogCommonButtons.Close;
dialog.DefaultButton = TaskDialogResult.Close; // optional, will default to first button in box if unassigned
TaskDialogResult response = test.Show();
```

This type of framework would then be used on a window/form/user control that's used by multiple different modules, each with slightly different UI needs. Most modules will need a list box and Confirm/OK and Cancel buttons as a basis, but some will need additional buttons for additional functionality within the window.

If this functionality is better done in WinForms, I'm open to moving my GUI to that platform, I have interacted with both in the past and am somewhat familiar with the flow of each, just not the more advanced topics yet. This said, the data binding is an important feature for me, so wpf is preferred.

Any input would be greatly appreciated!

---

### Edit

So, after some more digging around, I think I have a better understanding of how to ask my question:

What I want is the ability to programmatically add buttons (not RadioButtons like in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum)) to a window (wpf or winforms) by setting a variable in using the constructed window instance in the main code, passing it values from an enum with [Flags]. I want to have defined, common buttons (e.g. OK, Cancel, Close, etc) whose information and enum for adding to my window are in a module. I can then access these buttons through their enum, as Revit API allows with the `TaskDialogCommonButtons` enum, and assign them to a property of the window (in my example that would be the `TaskDialog.CommonButtons` property). This would then tell the window to show these buttons and none of the other buttons contained within the enum.

Unfortunately, the only results I get are how to data bind RadioButtons (not regular Buttons) that are then explicitly created within, or hard coded into, the xaml or codebehind of a window class and not dynamically added after the custom window class has been instantiated from the main code. This is clearly possible, otherwise the Revit API would not work in the way it does, but I can't seem to find anything relating to how or why it works and how to duplicate it.

Is simply a matter of including all of these buttons as hidden in the window class and using the enum to set the window instance's button visibility to show/true, thereby granting UI access? Or is it actually possible to add buttons programmatically from the driving code (not the codebehind of the window) using an enum?

Comment: I think the better way is to use WinForms of WPF, it will give you more space to show and receive data.

Comment: But does it have a way to add/set buttons to a framework/template window as with the third code line above (`dialog.CommonButtons...`)? I haven't been able to get a search result that specifically outlines how to do that.

Comment: yes you can define a bunch of buttons for each dialog