# Selecting an already selected RadioButton will select all RadioButtons

Tags: wpf, enums, binding, radio-button

I have two radio buttons and are binding them to an enum
Like in [How to bind RadioButtons to an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/397556/how-to-bind-radiobuttons-to-an-enum)

```
namespace RadioButtons
{
    public enum WorkModeEnum
    {
        Auto,
        Manual,
    }
}
```

```
<Window
    x:Class="RadioButtons.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RadioButtons"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    ContentRendered="Window_ContentRendered"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <local:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="ComparisonConverter" />
            </StackPanel.Resources>
            <RadioButton Content="Auto" IsChecked="{Binding Path=WorkMode, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ComparisonConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:WorkModeEnum.Auto}}" />
            <RadioButton Content="Manual" IsChecked="{Binding Path=WorkMode, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ComparisonConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:WorkModeEnum.Manual}}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace RadioButtons
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ViewModel _vm;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _vm = new ViewModel();
            DataContext = _vm;
        }
    }
}
```

The converter code looks like this

```
public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((Enum)value).HasFlag((Enum)parameter);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
        }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace RadioButtons
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ViewModel()
        {
            WorkMode = WorkModeEnum.Manual;
        }

        private WorkModeEnum _WorkMode;

        public WorkModeEnum WorkMode
        {
            get { return _WorkMode; }
            set
            {
                _WorkMode = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works, except for when the user click on the Manual button when it's already selected!
Then both of the buttons will show selected!

[image]

**Why and how fix it?**

The whole project is accessible (hopefully, I have never done this before) at

https://github.com/Andis59/RadioButtons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the Converter. You are using a normal Enum but the converter treat it as `[Flags]` (which are a kind of different).

`Enum.HasFlag(flag)` will always return `true` if the ordinal value of the given flag is `0`. Your `WorkModeEnum.Auto` has that ordinal value of `0` and causing this.

You could fix this by changing the `WorkModeEnum` definition to

```
public enum WorkModeEnum
{
    Auto = 1,
    Manual = 2,
}
```

but it is much better to fix the Converter

```
public class EnumToBooleanConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((Enum)parameter).Equals((Enum)value);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(true) ? parameter : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what's happening when you copy code without understanding...
Thank you very much!

Comment: Just in case you want to have more (and easier) binding, read https://brianlagunas.com/a-better-way-to-data-bind-enums-in-wpf/