# Get databinding object in control

Tags: c#, data-binding, enums

I want to create an enumcombobox where the popup will show the enumvalues of the controls' binding object. Somehow I cannot get the binding object property at runtime. Databindings wil get me to the binding object. But the property and its type is invisable for me, or I just didn't find it yet... Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Duplicate question... see this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538072/what-is-the-best-way-to-populate-a-wpf-combo-box-with-all-items-from-a-given-enum/848187#848187

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a DataObjectProvider. In your resources, put something like :

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" x:Key="odpEnum">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="yourEnumNameHere"/>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
```

In your combo, put :

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource odpEnum}}"/>
```

This should fill your combo with your enum.