# Display a ListBox with a List of enums

Tags: wpf, binding

I'm trying to display a `ListBox` inside of a `GridViewColumn` that needs to bind to a List of enums (`List<ResourceType> Cost`). The `GridViewColumn`'s `ListView` is already bound to a collection of objects and I'm not really sure the best way to go about displaying the `ListBox`. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the `ListBox` to a list of enum values. An easy way to do that is to use the markup extension I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538072/what-is-the-best-way-to-populate-a-wpf-combo-box-with-all-items-from-a-given-enum/848187#848187).

Then, you need to bind the `SelectedItem` of the `ListBox` to the property displayed in the `GridViewColumn`.

You should end up with something like that :

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Resource type">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{local:EnumValues local:ResourceType}"
                     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedResourceType}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

---

EDIT: I think I misread your question... If I understand correctly, each object displayed in the `ListView` has a `Cost` property of type `List<ResourceType>`, right ? (btw, the fact that `ResourceType` is an enum doesn't matter here). So you just need to bind the `ListBox` to the `Cost` property :

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Resource type">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cost}">
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: You beat me to it. You are correct. The first interpretation was a little off, but your edit hits the nail on the head. Curious though; why does it not matter that the `ResourceType` is an `enum`? Is it because WPF automatically calls the `ToString()` method on the selected `enum` and displays it? Thanks for the fast answer by the way.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Unless a DataTemplate is defined for the type, ToString is called to get a representation of the object