# How to add event on radio button change with MVVM pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to make dynamic radio buttons and I want to display a message box with the selected item on radio button change event. I don't really understand how to create a new event handler with MVVM pattern neither how `PropertyChangedEventHandler` can be used.

Here is my code

XAML

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
    <TextBlock Text="Select a Salad"
                       FontSize="18"
                        Margin="5" />
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Salads}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <RadioButton GroupName="Salads"
                            Content="{Binding ItemDescription}"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
                            Margin="5,1"/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

View Model

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Salads = new Collection<SelectableItem>
                {
                    new SelectableItem { ItemDescription = "Kale Avocado", Id = 1},
                    new SelectableItem { ItemDescription = "Caesar", Id = 2 },
                    new SelectableItem { ItemDescription = "Arugula with Goat Cheese", Id = 3, IsSelected = true},
                    new SelectableItem { ItemDescription = "Garden", Id = 4}
                };
    }

    // Salads
    public Collection<SelectableItem> Salads { get; set; }

    public SelectableItem SelectedSalad
    {
        get { return Salads.FirstOrDefault(s => s.IsSelected); }
    }

    // Property Changed
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

SelectableItem Class

```
public class SelectableItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string ItemDescription { get; set; }

    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data bound radio button list in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805015/data-bound-radio-button-list-in-wpf)

Comment: use ListBox instead of ItemsControl: ListBox has selection support out-of-box

Comment: Add an `ICommand` property to `SelectableItem` and bind the Command property of the `RadioButton` to this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically use commands to handle events in a MVVM application. Please refer to [this](http://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/) blog post for more information about this.

Once you have added a command to your `SelectableItem` class that displays the `MessageBox`, you could bind the `Command` property of the `RadioButton` to this source property:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Salads"
        Content="{Binding ItemDescription}"
        IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"
        Command="{Binding YourCommand}"
        Margin="5,1"/>
```

The command will then be invoked when you check or uncheck the `RadioButton`.

Answer (score 0):

PropertyChanged can be used like this

```
PropertyChanged += delegate(string propertyName)
{
    if(propertyName == "IsSelected")
    {
        // Do something
    }
};
```

Comment: for examlple in the constructor of MainWindowViewModel() or in the window/usercontrol's constructor (DataContext.OnPropertyChanged += ...)