# Trouble displaying Enums in a Combobox in WF4

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to follow the solution from this post in my WF4 project: [Databinding an enum property to a ComboBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743/databinding-an-enum-property-to-a-combobox-in-wpf#62032)

And I've implemented the code

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues"
    ObjectType="{x:Type s:Enum}"
    x:Key="DayOfWeekValues">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="s:DayOfWeek" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DayOfWeekValues}}"/>
```

I'm getting the following error on the TypeName="s:DayOfWeek" property.

```
Cannot reparent the node "Type(System.DayOfWeek)" from the old parent "IList" to the new parent "ObjectDataProvider".
```

Any ideas about what this error means?

**EDIT:** In addition to the error above, I'm also getting the following error on the MethodName="GetValues" property on the ObjectDataProvider.

```
INCORRECT_PARAMETER_TYPE
```

Comment: To followup, even though I was getting the error, I tried to use the activity anyway. There was no problem using the activity in my main workflow. It found the enum values just fine.

Comment: I was impatient about getting that "reparenting" error as well but it compiles nonetheless. Thanks for the tip !

Answer (score 5):

Just rebuild (not build) the solution or rebuild the project and it will work just fine.