# How to set a MenuItem's IsChecked property for a child of type Enum via XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, enums

I've bound a MenuItem to a Enum using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807724).

The Enum Values are displayed correctly, yet I cannot seem to set a default checked value for the MenuItem's children items.

Alternatively put, I would like the MenuItem to have one of its children items (the values of the enum I'm using) checked per default.

I've tried the following code, using a Style and a triggered Setter :

```
<ContextMenu>
  <MenuItem Header="Some Setting" Name="SomeSettingMenu" DataContext="{Binding}" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DisplayTypeValues}}" 
            Click="SomeSettingClicked">                          

    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsCheckable" Value="True"/>

        <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="enums:AnEnum.ItemA" >
            <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsChecked" Value="True"/>
          </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

      </Style>                            
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>

  </MenuItem>
</ContextMenu>
```

The enum contains values such as ItemA, I've also tried `AnEnum.First` or `0` in the Trigger Value attribute (as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165402/question-on-initial-value-of-an-enum-c)), to no avail.

Would a `DataTrigger` be advisable ? If so, how can I write that in XAML ?
Or should I use an `DataTemplate` within an `ItemTemplate` for the `MenuItem` ?

I've also tried fiddling around in code-behind with `SomeSetting.Items` -related methods, yet most of the properties (such as Current) are read-only.

I am aware that you can write `SomeSettingMenu.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(....))` in code-behind, but yet again I don't know how to select an Item within the MenuItem programmatically.

I've also tried this code, doesn't work as well :

```
<Style.Triggers>
  <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Header}" Value="enums:DisplayType.ItemA">
    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
  </DataTrigger>                 
</Style.Triggers>
```

`enums` is a namespace from a different assembly I'm using.

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thank you in advance !

Comment: I've found this article (http://neilmosafi.blogspot.com/2007/08/feb-07-using-combobox-to-select-enum.html) yet when I try to adapt it for my MenuItem a nice looking Exception is thrown. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your solution consider changing

```
<Trigger Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="enums:AnEnum.ItemA" >
```

to

```
<Trigger Property="MenuItem.Header" Value="{x:Static enums:AnEnum.ItemA}" >
```

in your example you check that header is equal to **sting "enums:AnEnum.ItemA"** not to enum AnEnum member ItemA.

Comment: That sounds like really good news, I'll check it out and let you know, thank your for your input on this question as well !

Answer (score 2):

You can do this. This will Bind to the child MenuItem's DataContext, which is "ItemA" for the first item.

```
<MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle> 
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsCheckable" Value="True"/>
        <Style.Triggers> 
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="ItemA">
                <Setter Property="MenuItem.IsChecked" Value="True"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
```