# WPF ComboBox 2-Way Binding

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a simple `ComboBox` that has some simple values. I'm trying to do 2 way binding with an enum property on my model.

```
<ComboBox d:LayoutOverrides="Height" Grid.Column="1" SelectedItem="{Binding SortType, Converter={StaticResource sortSelect}, Mode=TwoWay}">
      <ListBoxItem Content="Ascending" Tag="Ascending"/>
      <ListBoxItem Content="Descending" Tag="Descending"/>
      <ListBoxItem Content="Absolute Ascending" Tag="AbsoluteAscending"/>
      <ListBoxItem Content="Absolute Descending" Tag="AbsoluteDescending" />
    </ComboBox>
```

Here is my `ValueConverter`

```
public class RdiSortMatchConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var val = (RdiSort) value;
        switch (val)
        {
            case RdiSort.Ascending:
                return "Ascending";
            case RdiSort.Descending:
                return "Descending";
            case RdiSort.AbsoluteAscending:
                return "Absolute Ascending";
            case RdiSort.AbsoluteDescending:
                return "Absolute Descending";
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (RdiSort) Enum.Parse(typeof (RdiSort), (string) ((ListBoxItem) value).Tag);
    }
}
```

The `ConvertBack` method works fine, and updates my model based on the `Tag` value in the `ListBoxItem`, but I cant get the initial `Enum` value to select the correct `ListBoxItem`

whats the best way about achieving this, or is there a better way of binding t `Enums` (take into consideration that I need custom descriptions for each `Enum` value.

Comment: See this question: [Databinding an enum property to a ComboBox in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743/databinding-an-enum-property-to-a-combobox-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this. First add a description for each of your Enum values

```
public enum RdiSort
{ 
    [Description("Ascending Description")] 
    Ascending, 
    [Description("Descending Description")] 
    Descending, 
    [Description("AbsoluteAscending Description")] 
    AbsoluteAscending,
    [Description("AbsoluteDescending Description")] 
    AbsoluteDescending
}
```

Then use an ObjectDataProvider for your ComboBox

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
xmlns:MyEnumerations="clr-namespace:MyEnumerations" 

<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" 
                    ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" 
                    x:Key="RdiSortValues"> 
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters> 
        <x:Type TypeName="MyEnumerations:RdiSort" /> 
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters> 
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

Use the RdiSortValues provider in your ComboBox and create a DataTemplate with a TextBlock and a Converter to see the Description instead of the Enum value.

```
<local:EnumDescriptionConverter x:Key="EnumDescriptionConverter"/>

<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SortType}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RdiSortValues}}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource EnumDescriptionConverter}}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

And finally the converter. There is no need to ConvertBack since the converter is only used in the TextBlock for displaying.

```
public class EnumDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private string GetEnumDescription(Enum enumObj)
    {
        FieldInfo fieldInfo = enumObj.GetType().GetField(enumObj.ToString());
        object[] attribArray = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(false);
        if (attribArray.Length == 0)
        {
            return enumObj.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            DescriptionAttribute attrib = attribArray[0] as DescriptionAttribute;
            return attrib.Description;
        }
    }

    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            RdiSort myEnum = (RdiSort)value;
            string description = GetEnumDescription(myEnum);
            return description;
        }
        return null;
    }
    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution which I have done.

.xaml =>

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <c:PriorityConvertor x:Key="priorityConvertor"></c:PriorityConvertor>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

.cs file =>

```
public class PriorityConvertor : IValueConverter
{

    #region IValueConverter Members

    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        if (value.ToString() == "1")
        {
            return "High";
        }
        else if (value.ToString()  == "2")
        {
            return "Medium";
        }
        else if (value.ToString()  == "3")
        {
            return "Low";
        }
        return "Low";
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}