# Programmatically set selected item in a WPF combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a combobox that is bound to an enum using the following code:

```
cmb.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DATABASE_TYPES)).Cast<DATABASE_TYPES>();
```

where DATABASE_TYPES is:

```
public enum DATABASE_TYPES
        {
            JDataStore, Access, SQLServer, H2, PostGresSQL, MySQL
        };
```

I have some xml that matches one of the enum values:

```
<property name="Database.Main.Type"
        type="databaseType"
        default="JDataStore"
        permissions="superuser">
    </property>
```

I am trying to programmatically set the selected item of the combobox to the default value from the xml.

I have tried:

```
cmb.SelectedItem = propertyNode.Attributes["default"].Value;
```

but this doesn't work.

Could someone please advise?

Comment: You may want to see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9242345/show-enum-in-a-combobox/9327548#9327548 that allows you to localize the text displayed in the combo box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the string to an enum instance:

```
cmb.SelectedItem = (DATABASE_TYPES)Enum.Parse(typeof(DATABASE_TYPES), propertyNode.Attributes["default"].Value);
```

Comment: Brilliant. I havent worked with enums much in the past. Looks like I have to get my head around them. Thanks Will mark as answer as soon as I can

Answer (score 0):

You could also get a list of strings from the `enum` and your code works as it is

```
 cmb.ItemsSource = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DATABASE_TYPES));
```