# WPF Databind friendly enum error

Tags: wpf, data-binding

In order to bind a 'friendly' enum I follow this link

[Databinding an enum property to a ComboBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743/databinding-an-enum-property-to-a-combobox-in-wpf)

but I have this error:Unable to create 'Type' from the 'Status' string

this is my code behind

```
    public enum Status
    {
        [Description("Available.")]
        Available,
        [Description("Not here right now.")]
        Away,
        [Description("I don't have time right now.")]
        Busy
    }


    public Status CurrentStatus { get; set; }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
```

and this is my XAML

```
<Grid>
    <ComboBox 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={my:Enumeration {x:Type Status}}}" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
        SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentStatus}"  
        SelectedValuePath="Value"  />

</Grid>
```

what's I wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a namespace.  If your code is in a namespace called `MyProject` then you need to add a reference to that at the top of your xaml file:

```
    <xmlns:proj="clr-namespace:MyProject" />
```

and then prefix your type accordingly:

```
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={my:Enumeration {x:Type proj:Status}}}"
```

EDIT: looking at your existing markup, using `my:Status` might be enough.

Comment: sorry I have:xmlns:my="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3" ..and ItemsSource="{Binding Source={my:Enumeration {x:Type my:Status}}}" but the error are the same

Comment: In which namespace is your type `Status` defined?

Comment: Well, is it called `Status` or `Status1`?

Comment: Ah, wait: have you nested your `enum` declaration *inside* your `MainWindow` class?  If so, your class is actually called `my:MainWindow.Status`...

Comment: yes it is in MainWindow but with {x:Type my:MainWindow.Status} I have tha same error ...incredible but if I move in another class in the same assembly with this {x:Type my:Class1+Status} (reshaper help me suggesting '+' works !!! ...you are show me the way thanks