# How to pass the Type of a object through XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to get a type object in XAML.

```
x:Type={...}
```

But I realized that Silverlight does not support it. I was trying to use it in the following question (in `EnumerationExtension` class):

[Databinding an enum property to a ComboBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743/databinding-an-enum-property-to-a-combobox-in-wpf)

What can I do to pass the type in XAML?C

Answer (score 1):

if SL 5 then custom [`MarkupExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712747.aspx)
else `Binding` with [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that returns `value.GetType()`

---

ME example:

```
public class TypeExtension : IMarkupExtension<Type>
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }

    public TypeExtension() { }
    public TypeExtension(string typeName)
        : this()
    {
        if (typeName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("typeName");

        TypeName = typeName;
    }

    public Type ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var typeResolver = (IXamlTypeResolver)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IXamlTypeResolver));
        var type = typeResolver.Resolve(TypeName);
        return type;
    }
}
```

Note that there is no support for the constructors in SL 5, so you need to use the property names in XAML:

```xml
{me:Type TypeName=local:SomeClass}
```

Comment: I'm using SL5. I have a doubt, so have I create a MyType custom markup extension and set the PrivideValue the object.GetType right?

Answer (score 0):

You could [create a Custom Markup Extension](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jprosise/archive/2011/04/15/using-custom-markup-extensions-in-silverlight-5.aspx) (available since Silverlight 5)

Or you could [use this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/305932/Static-and-Type-markup-extensions-for-Silverlight)