# C# VB.net translation

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to implement an example from this thread [Databinding an enum property to a ComboBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743/databinding-an-enum-property-to-a-combobox-in-wpf) but I need to translate it to VB.net. It's Martin Liversage's answer.

It's about these 2 lines:

```
this.valueToNameMap = this.type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).ToDictionary(fi => fi.GetValue(null), GetDescription);
this.nameToValueMap = this.valueToNameMap.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Value, kvp => kvp.Key);
```

Thanks!

Comment: You could tried a very simple google search "convert c# to vb.net" an click on the first result

Comment: Sorry for being alive! I always used this one http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/ but it makes a mess of it. Didn't know about telerik.

Comment: No. people here are interested in only real programming problems, that you cannot find using search.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Me.valueToNameMap = Me.type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static Or BindingFlags.Public).ToDictionary(Function(fi) fi.GetValue(Nothing), GetDescription)
Me.nameToValueMap = Me.valueToNameMap.ToDictionary(Function(kvp) kvp.Value, Function(kvp) kvp.Key)
```