# Change displayed text of WPF ComboBox containing an Enum?

Tags: c#, wpf, enums

**Situation:**

C# with WPF and .NET 4.5.

I have an Enum defined in an external library. Let´s say it´s called *SomeEnum* and contains items "*SomeValue1*", "*SomeValue2*, "*SomeValue3*", and many more.

I have a ComboBox filled with these values like this:

```
comboBoxValues.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum));
```

The ComboBox, as expected, shows:

> SomeValue1
>
> SomeValue2
>
> SomeValue3
>
> ...

**Question:**

Can I somehow change only the displayed values so that the "*Some*" part is missing.
So that the ComboBox only shows this:

> Value1
>
> Value2
>
> Value3
>
> ...

But: The *SelectedValue* for "*Value1*" should still be "*SomeValue1*".

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ to just trim the strings:

```
comboBoxValues.ItemsSource = Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum)).Select(x => x.ToString().TrimStart("Value"));
```

But to be honest I would suggest making a two way converter, so that then you can bind `SelectedItem` to `SomeEnum SomeProperty {get;set;}` or setting up a Dictionary like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58743/databinding-an-enum-property-to-a-combobox-in-wpf)